# How do I remove a substring from the end of a string (remove a suffix of the string)?

Tags: python, string

I have the following code:

```
url = 'abcdc.com'
print(url.strip('.com'))
```

I expected: `abcdc`

I got: `abcd`

Now I do

```
url.rsplit('.com', 1)
```

Is there a better way?

---

<sub>See [How do the .strip/.rstrip/.lstrip string methods work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990694) for a specific explanation of what the first attempt is doing.</sub>

Comment: __strip__ strips the characters given from both ends of the string, in your case it strips ".", "c", "o" and "m".

Comment: It will also remove those characters from the front of the string. If you just want it to remove from the end, use rstrip()

Comment: Yeah.  str.strip doesn't do what you think it does.

str.strip removes any of the characters specified from the beginning and the end of the string.  So, "acbacda".strip("ad") gives 'cbac'; the a at the beginning and the da at the end were stripped.

Cheers.

Comment: Plus, this removes the characters in *any order*: "site.ocm" > "site".

Comment: Also removes duplicates. "cooldom.com">"ld"

Comment: @scvalex, wow just realised this having used it that way for ages - it's dangerous because the code often happens to work anyway

Comment: You meant `rstrip`?

Comment: @AndreMiller In this specific case even `rstrip()` won't work because in the string `'abcdc.com'` it will just leave `abcd` as it has a `c` just before the dot.

Comment: What's wrong with rsplit? Your solution already seems like the best one to me.

Answer (score 877, accepted):

[`strip`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) doesn't mean "remove this substring". `x.strip(y)` treats `y` as a set of characters and strips any characters in that set from both ends of `x`.

On **Python 3.9 and newer** you can use the [`removeprefix`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) and [`removesuffix`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix) methods to remove an entire substring from either side of the string:

```
url = 'abcdc.com'
url.removesuffix('.com')    # Returns 'abcdc'
url.removeprefix('abcdc.')  # Returns 'com'
```

The relevant Python Enhancement Proposal is [PEP-616](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/).

On **Python 3.8 and older** you can use [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) and slicing:

```
url = 'abcdc.com'
if url.endswith('.com'):
    url = url[:-4]
```

Or a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
import re
url = 'abcdc.com'
url = re.sub('\.com$', '', url)
```

Comment: Which would be better??
re.sub('\.com$', '', url)
url.rsplit('.com', 1)[0]
Or are both, different ways to solve the problem..

Comment: Yeah, I myself think that the first example, with the endswith() test, would be the better one; the regex one would involve some performance penalty (parsing the regex, etc.). I wouldn't go with the rsplit() one, but that's because I don't know what you're exactly trying to achieve. I figure it's removing the .com if and only if it appears at the end of the url? The rsplit solution would give you trouble if you'd use it on domain names like 'www.commercialthingie.co.uk'

Comment: `url = url[:-4] if any(url.endswith(x) for x in ('.com','.net')) else url`

Comment: what if I write `EXAMLPLE.COM` domain names are not case sensitive. (This is a vote for the regex solution)

Comment: Regarding the first solution: Why rewrite rsplit()? It's already in the language: `url=url.rsplit(".com",1)[0]` -1

Comment: It is not a rewrite, the `rsplit()` solution doesn't have the same behaviour as the `endswith()` one when the original string does not have the substring at the end, but somewhere in the middle. For instance: `"www.comeandsee.com".rsplit(".com",1)[0] == "www.comeandsee"` but `"www.comeandsee.net".rsplit(".com",1)[0] == "www"`

Comment: The syntax `s[:-n]` has a caveat: for `n = 0`, this doesn't return the string with the last zero characters chopped off, but the empty string instead.

Comment: As of python 3.6, regexes should be marked as such - `url = re.sub(r'\.com$', '', url)`  (note the `r` in front of it the regex) - see https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/W605.html

Answer (score 110):

If you are sure that the string only appears at the end, then the simplest way would be to use 'replace':

```
url = 'abcdc.com'
print(url.replace('.com',''))
```

Comment: that will also replace url like `www.computerhope.com`. do a check with `endswith()` and should be fine.

Comment: `"www.computerhope.com".endswith(".com")` is true, it still will break!

Comment: "If you are sure that the string only appears at the end" do you mean "If you are sure that the substring appears only once" ? replace seems to work also when the substring is in the middle, but as the other comment suggests it will replace any occurence of the substring, why it should be at the end I dont understand

Answer (score 73):

```
def strip_end(text, suffix):
    if suffix and text.endswith(suffix):
        return text[:-len(suffix)]
    return text
```

Comment: @Boris I liked it before, without the extra check of whether suffix is empty

Comment: @yarichu I copied the code from [PEP 616](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/) that introduced this exact function into the stdlib. The reason I also think this way is better is that the reason you have to do `len(text)-len(suffix)` is unclear when you can just use negative indices in Python (in fact, you fixed that bug in an edit and there used to be a comment here incorrectly telling you that you don't need the `len(text)`, so this seems error prone), whereas `if suffix` makes it clear exactly what you're _actually_ checking and why.

Answer (score 60):

Since it seems like nobody has pointed this on out yet:

```
url = "www.example.com"
new_url = url[:url.rfind(".")]
```

This should be more efficient than the methods using `split()` as no new list object is created, and this solution works for strings with several dots.

Comment: Wow that is a nice trick. I couldn't get this to fail but I also had a hard time being able to think up ways this might fail. I like it but it is very "magical", hard to know what this does by just looking at it. I had to mentally process each part of line to "get it".

Comment: This fails if the searched-for string is NOT present, and it wrongly removes the last character instead.

Answer (score 33):

Starting in `Python 3.9`, you can use [`removesuffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix) instead:

```
'abcdc.com'.removesuffix('.com')
# 'abcdc'
```

Comment: And the python code from the specification can be found in [PEP 616](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/#specification)

Answer (score 28):

Depends on what you know about your url and exactly what you're tryinh to do.  If you know that it will always end in '.com' (or '.net' or '.org') then

```
 url=url[:-4]
```

is the quickest solution. If it's a more general URLs then you're probably better of looking into the urlparse library that comes with python.

If you on the other hand you simply want to remove everything after the final '.' in a string then

```
url.rsplit('.',1)[0]
```

will work.  Or if you want just want everything up to the first '.' then try

```
url.split('.',1)[0]
```

Answer (score 17):

If you know it's an extension, then

```
url = 'abcdc.com'
...
url.rsplit('.', 1)[0]  # split at '.', starting from the right, maximum 1 split
```

This works equally well with `abcdc.com` or `www.abcdc.com` or `abcdc.[anything]` and is more extensible.

Comment: This seems the most obvious and cleanest way to me. Doesn't have to be an extension though, you can just split on the whole substring to be matched.

Answer (score 15):

On Python 3.9+:

```
text.removesuffix(suffix)
```

On any Python version:

```
def remove_suffix(text, suffix):
    return text[:-len(suffix)] if text.endswith(suffix) and len(suffix) != 0 else text
```

or the one-liner:

```
remove_suffix = lambda text, suffix: text[:-len(suffix)] if text.endswith(suffix) and len(suffix) != 0 else text
```

Comment: Or `text[:-len(suffix)] if suffix and text.endswith(suffix) else text`

Answer (score 7):

How about `url[:-4]`?

Comment: Seems almost guaranteed to lead to a bug once you get hit with a `.ca` or `.co.uk` url.

Answer (score 6):

For urls (as it seems to be a part of the topic by the given example), one can do something like this:

```
import os
url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
name,ext = os.path.splitext(url)
print (name, ext)

#Or:
ext = '.'+url.split('.')[-1]
name = url[:-len(ext)]
print (name, ext)
```

Both will output:
`('http://www.stackoverflow', '.com')`

This can also be combined with `str.endswith(suffix)` if you need to just split ".com", or anything specific.

Answer (score 6):

**DSCLAIMER** This method has a critical flaw in that the partition is not anchored to the end of the url and may return spurious results. For example, the result for the URL "www.comcast.net" is "www" (incorrect) instead of the expected "www.comcast.net". This solution therefore is *evil*. Don't use it unless you know what you are doing!

```
url.rpartition('.com')[0]
```

This is fairly easy to type and also correctly returns the original string (no error) when the suffix '.com' is missing from `url`.

Comment: +1 partition is preferred when only one split is needed since it always returns an answer, an IndexError won't occur.

Comment: This doesn't correctly handle the suffix not being there. For example, it will incorrectly return `www` for `www.comcast.net`.

Comment: That's a really excellent point @Boris! Thank you so much for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to remove the domain, no matter what it is (.com, .net, etc). I recommend finding the `.` and removing everything from that point on.

```py
url = 'abcdc.com'
dot_index = url.rfind('.')
url = url[:dot_index]
```

Here I'm using `rfind` to solve the problem of urls like `abcdc.com.net` which should be reduced to the name `abcdc.com`.

If you're also concerned about `www.`s, you should explicitly check for them:

```py
if url.startswith("www."):
   url = url.replace("www.","", 1)
```

The 1 in replace is for strange edgecases like `www.net.www.com`

If your url gets any wilder than that look at the regex answers people have responded with.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean to only strip the extension:

```
'.'.join('abcdc.com'.split('.')[:-1])
# 'abcdc'
```

It works with any extension, with potential other dots existing in filename as well. It simply splits the string as a list on dots and joins it without the last element.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to strip some end of a string if it exists otherwise do nothing. My best solutions. You probably will want to use one of first 2 implementations however I have included the 3rd for completeness.

For a constant suffix:

```
def remove_suffix(v, s):
    return v[:-len(s)] if v.endswith(s) else v
remove_suffix("abc.com", ".com") == 'abc'
remove_suffix("abc", ".com") == 'abc'
```

For a regex:

```
def remove_suffix_compile(suffix_pattern):
    r = re.compile(f"(.*?)({suffix_pattern})?$")
    return lambda v: r.match(v)[1]
remove_domain = remove_suffix_compile(r"\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}")
remove_domain("abc.com") == "abc"
remove_domain("sub.abc.net") == "sub.abc"
remove_domain("abc.") == "abc."
remove_domain("abc") == "abc"
```

For a collection of constant suffixes the asymptotically fastest way for a large number of calls:

```
def remove_suffix_preprocess(*suffixes):
    suffixes = set(suffixes)
    try:
        suffixes.remove('')
    except KeyError:
        pass

    def helper(suffixes, pos):
        if len(suffixes) == 1:
            suf = suffixes[0]
            l = -len(suf)
            ls = slice(0, l)
            return lambda v: v[ls] if v.endswith(suf) else v
        si = iter(suffixes)
        ml = len(next(si))
        exact = False
        for suf in si:
            l = len(suf)
            if -l == pos:
                exact = True
            else:
                ml = min(len(suf), ml)
        ml = -ml
        suffix_dict = {}
        for suf in suffixes:
            sub = suf[ml:pos]
            if sub in suffix_dict:
                suffix_dict[sub].append(suf)
            else:
                suffix_dict[sub] = [suf]
        if exact:
            del suffix_dict['']
            for key in suffix_dict:
                suffix_dict[key] = helper([s[:pos] for s in suffix_dict[key]], None)
            return lambda v: suffix_dict.get(v[ml:pos], lambda v: v)(v[:pos])
        else:
            for key in suffix_dict:
                suffix_dict[key] = helper(suffix_dict[key], ml)
            return lambda v: suffix_dict.get(v[ml:pos], lambda v: v)(v)
    return helper(tuple(suffixes), None)
domain_remove = remove_suffix_preprocess(".com", ".net", ".edu", ".uk", '.tv', '.co.uk', '.org.uk')
```

the final one is probably significantly faster in pypy then cpython. The regex variant is likely faster than this for virtually all cases that do not involve huge dictionaries of potential suffixes that cannot be easily represented as a regex at least in cPython.

In PyPy the regex variant is almost certainly slower for large number of calls or long strings even if the re module uses a DFA compiling regex engine as the vast majority of the overhead of the lambda's will be optimized out by the JIT.

In cPython however the fact that your running c code for the regex compare almost certainly outweighs the algorithmic advantages of the suffix collection version in almost all cases.

Edit: https://m.xkcd.com/859/

Answer (score 3):

Because this is a very popular question i add another, now available, solution. With python 3.9 (https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html) the function `removesuffix()` will be added (and `removeprefix()`) and this function is exactly what was questioned here.

```
url = 'abcdc.com'
print(url.removesuffix('.com'))
```

output:

```
'abcdc'
```

PEP 616 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/) shows how it will **behave** (it is not the real implementation):

```
def removeprefix(self: str, prefix: str, /) -> str:
    if self.startswith(prefix):
        return self[len(prefix):]
    else:
        return self[:]
```

and what **benefits** it has against self-implemented solutions:

1. **Less fragile**:
   The code will not depend on the user to count the length of a literal.
2. **More performant**:
   The code does not require a call to the Python built-in len function nor to the more expensive str.replace() method.
3. **More descriptive**:
   The methods give a higher-level API for code readability as opposed to the traditional method of string slicing.

Comment: Someone already posted about this 8 months before you did https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432508

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

def rm_suffix(url = 'abcdc.com', suffix='\.com'):
    return(re.sub(suffix+'$', '', url))
```

I want to repeat this answer as the most expressive way to do it. Of course, the following would take less CPU time:

```
def rm_dotcom(url = 'abcdc.com'):
    return(url[:-4] if url.endswith('.com') else url)
```

However, if CPU is the bottle neck why write in Python?

When is CPU a bottle neck anyway? In drivers, maybe.

The advantages of using regular expression is code reusability. What if you next want to remove '.me', which only has three characters?

Same code would do the trick:

```
>>> rm_sub('abcdc.me','.me')
'abcdc'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split:

```
'abccomputer.com'.split('.com',1)[0]
# 'abccomputer'
```

Comment: When `a = 'www.computerbugs.com'` this results with `'www`'

Comment: Can do it from the reverse end I guess? Not sure if there is a way to write it more readably: `'www.computerbugs.com'[::-1].split('.com'[::-1], 1)[-1][::-1]`

Comment: Ah rsplit is the way: `'www.computerbugs.com'.rsplit('.com', 1)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to raise an exception so I did:

```
class UnableToStripEnd(Exception):
    """A Exception type to indicate that the suffix cannot be removed from the text."""

    @staticmethod
    def get_exception(text, suffix):
        return UnableToStripEnd("Could not find suffix ({0}) on text: {1}."
                                .format(suffix, text))


def strip_end(text, suffix):
    """Removes the end of a string. Otherwise fails."""
    if not text.endswith(suffix):
        raise UnableToStripEnd.get_exception(text, suffix)
    return text[:len(text)-len(suffix)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A broader solution, adding the possibility to **replace the suffix** (you can remove by replacing with the empty string) and to **set the maximum number of replacements**:

```
def replacesuffix(s,old,new='',limit=1):
    """
    String suffix replace; if the string ends with the suffix given by parameter `old`, such suffix is replaced with the string given by parameter `new`. The number of replacements is limited by parameter `limit`, unless `limit` is negative (meaning no limit).

    :param s: the input string
    :param old: the suffix to be replaced
    :param new: the replacement string. Default value the empty string (suffix is removed without replacement).
    :param limit: the maximum number of replacements allowed. Default value 1.
    :returns: the input string with a certain number (depending on parameter `limit`) of the rightmost occurrences of string given by parameter `old` replaced by string given by parameter `new`
    """
    if s[len(s)-len(old):] == old and limit != 0:
        return replacesuffix(s[:len(s)-len(old)],old,new,limit-1) + new
    else:
        return s
```

In your case, given the default arguments, the desired result is obtained with:

```
replacesuffix('abcdc.com','.com')
>>> 'abcdc'
```

Some more general examples:

```
replacesuffix('whatever-qweqweqwe','qwe','N',2)
>>> 'whatever-qweNN'

replacesuffix('whatever-qweqweqwe','qwe','N',-1)
>>> 'whatever-NNN'

replacesuffix('12.53000','0',' ',-1)
>>> '12.53   '
```

Answer (score 1):

Function To Remove a Suffix in Python 3.8 :

```
def removesuffix(text, suffix):
if text.endswith(suffix):
    return text[:-len(suffix)]
else:
    return text
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use for regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r"(.*)\.com", "hello.com").group(1)
'hello'
```

Comment: You should also add a $ to make sure that you're matching hostnames *ending* in ".com".

Answer (score 0):

Use the public suffix list hosted by Mozilla. It's available as the `tldextract` python library.

```
import tldextract

url = 'abcdc.com'

# Extract the domain and TLD
extracted = tldextract.extract(url)
domain, tld = extracted.domain, extracted.suffix

if tld and tld != 'localhost':
    url_without_tld = domain
else:
    url_without_tld = url

print(url_without_tld)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here,i have a simplest code.

```
url=url.split(".")[0]
```

Comment: I think you mean `url = url.split(".")[:-1]`.

Answer (score -1):

## Using replace and count

This might seems a little bit a hack but it ensures you a safe replace without using `startswith` and if statement, using the `count` arg of replace you can limit the replace to one:

```
mystring = "www.comwww.com"
```

Prefix:

```
print(mystring.replace("www.","",1))
```

Suffix (you write the prefix reversed) `.com` becomes `moc.`:

```
print(mystring[::-1].replace("moc.","",1)[::-1])
```

Comment: Why would you do this ...

Answer (score -3):

I used the built-in [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip) function to do it like follow:

```
string = "test.com"
suffix = ".com"
newstring = string.rstrip(suffix)
print(newstring)
test
```

Comment: Bad idea. Try `"test.ccom"`.

Comment: But  this is not the point of the question. It was just asked to remove a known substring from the end of another. This works exactly as expected.

Comment: @Alex try your solution with mooc.com or maximo.com

Comment: Yes @lorenzo I tried now and it doesn't work properly because it eats everything. So although it works for the example it is not general enough. I tried with split and it works better but still not completely general:
In [13]: string = "testcom.cp.com" 
    ...: suffix = ".com" 
    ...: newstring = string.split(suffix) 
    ...: print(newstring[0])                                                                                                                                          
testcom.cp

Comment: Your answer demonstrates the same misunderstanding about what `strip`/`rstrip`/`lstrip` do as the person asking the question. They treat the string passed to them as a *set of characters* not a literal suffix/prefix to be removed. Please read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).

Comment: The question **already tries** this approach and **demonstrates the exact problem**.