# How to reassign a string after removing parts of it by index

Tags: python, string

I have a string

```
s = 'texttexttextblahblah",".'
```

and I want to cut of some of the rightmost characters by indexing and assign it to `s` so that `s` will be equal to `texttexttextblahblah"`.

I've looked around and found how to print by indexing, but not how to reassign that actual variable to be trimmed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Remove last 3 characters of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798465/python-remove-last-3-characters-of-a-string)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just reassign what you printed to the variable.

```
>>> s = 'texttexttextblahblah",".'
>>> s = s[:-3]
>>> s
'texttexttextblahblah"'
>>>
```

Unless you know exactly how many `text` and `blah`'s you'll have, use `.find()` as Brent suggested (or `.index(x)`, which is like find, except complains when it doesn't find `x`).

If you want that trailing `"`, just add one to the value it kicks out. (or just `find` the value you actually want to split at, `,`)

```
s = s[:s.find('"') + 1]
```

Answer (score 8):

If you **need** something that works like a string, but **is mutable** you can use a `bytearray`:

```
>>> s = bytearray('texttexttextblahblah",".')
>>> s[20:] = ''
>>> print s
texttexttextblahblah
```

`bytearray` has all the usual string methods.

Comment: Note that this answer only applies to Python 2.

Answer (score 5):

Strings are immutable so you can't really change the string in-place.  You'll need to slice out the part you want and then reassign it back over the original variable.

Is something like this what you wanted? (note I left out storing the index in a variable because I'm not sure how you're using this):

```
>>> s = 'texttexttextblahblah",".'
>>> s.index('"')
20
>>> s = s[:20]
>>> s
'texttexttextblahblah'
```

Answer (score 1):

I myself prefer to do it without indexing: (My favorite partition was commented as winner in speed and clearness in comments so I updated the original code)

```
s = 'texttexttextblahblah",".'
s,_,_ = s.partition(',')
print s
```

Result

```
texttexttextblahblah"
```

Comment: He wanted the " in the result (could be a typo), though.

Comment: `s=s[:s.find('"')]` is more efficient

Comment: I did the change myself, as I noticed it, I prefer more pythonic split or partition myself. That is, I prefer "Make it work in clear way, then optimize."

Comment: @Tony, in this case `partition` is more appropriate then, as it conveys that you are splitting something into two parts. `split` conveys the idea that you are splitting by a delimiter in multiple places.

Comment: `s = s.split(',',1)[0]` and you don't have to allocate a dummy variable.

Comment: `split()` is also 50% slower than `partition()` for this example

Comment: @Nick, still a lot slower than partition()

Comment: `s=s.partition(',')[0]` or `s,_,_=partition(',')` in case anyone reading the comments doesn't know about `str.partition`

Comment: @gnibbler: yeah, `partition()` is probably the best tool; was commenting back to OP about dumping the split to 2 variables, though not sure if that was just to illustrate it provides a length-2 iterable.

Comment: Is split really very slow? I liked idea from this forum that you can split 3 parts by doing: first, second, third, cdr = mytext.split(separator,3) (Ok, I do know Lisp)

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to partition. I can only comment on my requirements but it worked very well.