# Remove a string in every line

Tags: python

I have these input strings:

```
omarReturn
waelReturn
```

I want the output strings to be:

```
omar
wael
```

This is my code

```
 write = file("e", 'a')
    write.write(event.Key)

    if event.Key=="Return":
        read = file("e", 'r')
        lines = read.readlines()
        read.close()
        # How do I remove "Return" from the lines
        write.write("\n")
```

Comment: This stackoverflow question could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516571/python-remove-parts-of-string-by-index

Comment: Do you  want to remove any 'Return' or  Return at the end of line only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#text-munging). This will remove `"Return"` substring if it appears at the end, otherwise not.

Let's make a function `substring_remover()`

```
import re 
def substring_remover(whole_string):
    return re.sub(r'(.+)(Return)$',r'\1',whole_string)      

print substring_remover('omarReturn') # Will remove "Return" as it is at the end
print substring_remover('omarNormal') # Will remove nothing as there is no "Return"
print substring_remover('omarReturnExtra') # Will remove nothing because "Return" exists but not at the end.
```

Output:

```
omar
omarNormal
omarReturnExtra
```

So, the exact code will be:

```
with open('your_file','rw') as f:
    print '\n'.join([substring_remover(line) for line in f.read().splitlines()])  
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(value)
    f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove every "Return" from string "a".

So iterating to every of your lines and use this command while changing variable should work

```
a=a.replace("Return","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumes the input data is in a file named 'inputfile.txt' in the same folder as the Python code and that it is encoded in UTF-8.

```
# Open the input file for reading.
with open('inputfile.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    # Store all the data from the input file in a variable named
    #  'inlines'.  This only makes sense if you have a small amount
    #  of data, as you suggest you do.
    inlines = infile.readlines()

# Open or create a file named 'outputfile.txt' in the same folder as
#  'inputfile.txt' with UTF-8 encoding.
with open('outputfile.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    # Walk each line in the input file.
    for line in inlines:
        # Write each input line to the output file with 'Return'
        #  removed.
        outfile.write(line.replace('Return', ''))
```