# list.pop() functionality for strings in python

Tags: python, string, performance, list

In python, in order to remove the i'th element from a list we can run:

```
list.pop(index)
```

for example:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
a.pop(2)
print a
```

will result in:

> ```
> ['a','b','d','e']
> ```

But what is the best way to **perform such an action on a string**?

My best approach meanwhile is:

```
a = 'abcde'
a = a[:2]+a[2+1:]
print a
```

> ```
> 'abde'
> ```

[like it was mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3516590/3861108) (not a duplicate, I'm looking for a better approach)

it seems efficient, but if I iterate over a string it not that good anymore:

```
for i in len(a):
    if condition(a[i]):
       a = a[:i]+a[i+1:]
```

Comment: Looks like the best way to me. Since strings are immutable, you cannot hope for a solution that does not involve creating a new string and assigning it to `a`.

Comment: Strings in `python` are not mutable. So you have no other choice than recreate the string like you did.