# How can I receive a corresponding percentage when progressbar is clicked python3 gtk3

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I am writing a very simple and lightweight remote control for Kodi in python3 and GTK3. I was already able to add the progress bar that gets updated as playback progresses, but I would like to be able to click on a specific part of the progress bar and seek to corresponding part of the video.

Can someone please help me or at least orient me a little how can I achieve it? For now I am working with percentage, as it is much more simple than working with time.

The only thing I need for now is to get 0.33 as output when I click on 1/3 of the progress bar (obviously on the whole length of the progress bar accordingly)

I guess I have to be missing something very simple, but I cannot find what it is. I found one example of using EventBox, but it only informed about a mouse movement gesture, and was not able to give the specific number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came up with an answer for python3 and GTK3.

I posted the whole code here: https://github.com/elpraga/kodi-cli 
I will post the relevant bits here:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
import subprocess
```

...

```
    self.progressbar = Gtk.ProgressBar(text="Kodi is not playing at the moment")
    self.progresseventbox = Gtk.EventBox()
    self.progressbar.set_show_text(True)
```

...

```
    grid.attach(self.youtube_entry, 0, 0, 4, 1)
    grid.attach_next_to(self.progresseventbox, self.youtube_entry, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 4, 1)
    self.progresseventbox.add(self.progressbar)
```

...

```
    self.progresseventbox.connect("button-press-event", self.on_mouse_click)
```

...

```
def on_mouse_click(self, widget, event):
    width = self.progresseventbox.get_allocated_width()
    percentage = event.x / width * 100
    percentage = str(percentage)
    output = (subprocess.check_output(["kodi-cli", "-g", percentage]))
    # Let's get some response from kodi-cli
    output = (subprocess.check_output(["kodi-cli", "-g"]))
    output = output.decode('ascii')
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798465/python-remove-last-3-characters-of-a-string
    self.output_text.set_text(output)
```

...

[Screenshot of the clickable progress bar I used after all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD8KO.png)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution probably is to switch to the [`Gtk.Scale`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Scale.html#Gtk.Scale), because it already supports everything you need. A simple scale that prints it value on change would look like this (in python 2.7):

```
class GtkWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Dialog Example")

        min_val = 0.0
        max_val = 100.0
        adjustment = Gtk.Adjustment.new(0.0, min_val, max_val, 1.0, 10.0, 10.0)
        scale = Gtk.Scale.new(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, adjustment)
        scale.connect("value-changed", self.on_value_changed)
        self.add(scale)

    def on_value_changed(self, scale):
        print scale.get_value()

win = GtkWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```