# How to remove prefix from the given URL in python?

Tags: python, url

I know it's simple, but I want a nice method. How from url string like:

```
/en/something/123/foo/
```

get

```
/something/123/foo/
```

?

It means, I want to remove first level (prefix).

Comment: [This should answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038824/python-strip-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's always three characters long:

```
str = str[3:]
```

If it can be variable-length, using only string/list operations:

```
str = '/' + '/'.join( str.split('/')[2:] )
```

Or using regex:

```
import re
str = re.sub('^/[a-z]*', '', str)
```

I would probably use the last method. If you need to do this a lot (e.g. in a loop), consider compiling the regex using `re.compile()` to speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Building on richardolsson's answer, we can utilize the `maxsplit` parameter of `str.split`:

```
str = str.split("/", 2)[2]
```

This splits only the first two separators, and returns the rest (the third list item) unchanged.