# Scraping in Python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've read quite a few posts here about this, but I'm very new to Python in general so I was hoping for some more info.

Essentially, I'm trying to write something that will pull word definitions from a site and write them to a file. I've been using BeautifulSoup, and I've made quite some progress, but here's my issue -

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import urllib2, urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

wordlist = open('test.txt', 'a')

word = raw_input('Paste your word ')

url = 'http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/Default.aspx?action=define&dict=wn&query=%s' % word

# print url

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
# print html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
visible_text = soup.find('pre')(text=True)

print(visible_text, file=wordlist)
```

this seems to pull what I need, but puts it in this format

```
[u'passable\n     adj 1: able to be passed or traversed or crossed; &quot;the road is\n            passable&quot;
```

but I need it to be in plaintext. I've tried using a sanitizer (I was running it through bleach, but that didn't work. I've read some of the other answers here, but they don't explain HOW the code works, and I don't want to add something if I don't understand how it works.

Is there any way to just pull the plaintext?

edit: I ended up doing

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import urllib2, urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wordlist = open('test.txt', 'a')

word = raw_input('Paste your word ')

url = 'http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/Default.aspx?action=define&dict=wn&query=%s' % word

# print url

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
# print html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
visible_text = soup.find('pre')(text=True)[0]

print(visible_text, file=wordlist)
```

Comment: So what output do you actually want?  This is a list of unicode strings.  If you want, you could say: "for temp in visible_text: print(temp)" as your last line.

Comment: Or "for temp in visible_text: print(temp.strip())"

Comment: try to remove the chars u dont want
take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843518/remove-all-special-characters-punctuation-and-spaces-from-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843518/remove-all-special-characters-punctuation-and-spaces-from-string) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038824/how-do-i-remove-a-substring-from-the-end-of-a-string-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038824/how-do-i-remove-a-substring-from-the-end-of-a-string-in-python)

Comment: @DrXorile The output I'm looking for is what is seen on the page - something i can format afterward. Ultimately, I want to pass in a list of words, have it get all their definitions, and print it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

The code is already giving you [*plaintext*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text), it just happens to have some characters encoded as [entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML). In this case, *special characters*, which form part of the XML/HTML syntax are encoded to prevent them from breaking the structure of the text.

To decode them, use the `HTMLParser` module:

```
import HTMLParser
h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()

h.unescape('&quot;the road is passable&quot;')
>>> u'"the road is passable"'
```