# strip() vs lstrip() vs rstrip() in Python

Tags: python, string, character, difference, strip

I tried using `rstrip()` and `lstrip()` like so:

```
>>> a = 'thisthat'
>>> a.lstrip('this')
'at'
>>> a.rstrip('hat')
'this'
>>> a.rstrip('cat')
'thisth'
```

What exactly are these methods doing? I expected `'thist'` for the first case and `'that'` for the second case.

I'm not looking to fix the problem, I just want to understand the functionality.

---

<sub>See also [How do I remove a substring from the end of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038824) if you **do** want to fix a problem with removing something from the beginning or end of a string (or are trying to close such a duplicate question).</sub>

Comment: for learning about strip with some example usecases, I suggest have a look at following link https://www.dotnetperls.com/strip-python

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

> `str.`**`strip`**`([`*`chars`*`])`
> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. The *chars* argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or `None`, the *chars* argument defaults to removing whitespace. The *chars* argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

So, `strip` will try to remove *any of the characters listed in `chars`* from both ends as long as it can. That is, the string provided as an argument is considered as *a set of characters*, not as a substring.

`lstrip` and `rstrip` work the same way, except that `lstrip` only removes characters on the left (at the beginning) and `rstrip` only removes characters on the right (at the end).

Answer (score 4):

```
a = 'thisthat'    
a.rstrip('hat')
```

is equivalent to

```
a = 'thisthat' 
to_strip = 'hat'
while a[-1] in to_strip:
    a = a[:-1]
```

Comment: the slicing operator's end is not included, so it should be a = a[:-1] instead

Answer (score 1):

[strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) can remove all combinations of the spcific characters (spaces by default) from the left and right sides of string.

[lstrip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) can remove all combinations of the spcific characters (spaces by default) from the left sides of string.

[rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) can remove all combinations of the spcific characters (spaces by default) from the right sides of string.

```py
test = "    a b c    "

print(test)          # "    a b c    "
print(test.strip())  # "a b c"
print(test.lstrip()) # "a b c    "
print(test.rstrip()) # "    a b c"
```

```py
test = "abc a b c abc"

print(test)               # "abc a b c abc"
print(test.strip("cab"))  # " a b c "
print(test.lstrip("cab")) # " a b c abc"
print(test.rstrip("cab")) # "abc a b c "
```

```py
test = "abc a b c abc"

print(test)               # "abc a b c abc"
print(test.strip("c ab"))  # ""
print(test.lstrip("c ab")) # ""
print(test.rstrip("c ab")) # ""
```

Answer (score -1):

`lstrip`, `rstrip` and `strip` remove characters from the left, right and both ends of a string respectively. By default they remove whitespace characters (space, tabs, linebreaks, etc)

```
>>> a = '  string with spaces  '
>>> a.strip()
'string with spaces'
>>> a.lstrip()
'string with spaces  '
>>> a.rstrip()
'  string with spaces'
```

You can use the chars parameter to change the characters it strips.

```
>>> a = '....string....'
>>> a.strip('.')
'string'
```

However, based on your question it sounds like you are actually looking for replace

```
>>> a = 'thisthat'
>>> a.replace('hat', '')
'thist'
>>> a.replace('this', '')
'that'
```

Comment: @B Rad C No, I'm not looking for replace, I thought when i strip a word from the string it will take that substring and strips it off. I didn't know it takes chars as long as it can as Ahsanul Haque explained.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I understand the `lstrip` and `rstrip` methods:

```
#USING RSTRIP
a = 'thisthat'
print(a.rstrip('hat'))
#Begin with t on the right side, is t in 'hat'? Okay, remove it
#Next: a, is a in 'hat'? Okay remove it
#Next: h, is h in 'hat'? Okay, remove it
#Next: t, is t in 'hat'? Okay, remove it
#Next: s, is s in 'hat'? No, so, stop.
#Output: this

#USING LSTRIP
b = 'thisthat'
print(b.lstrip('this')) 
#Begin with t on the left side, is t in 'this'? Okay, remove it
#Next: h, is h in 'this'? Okay, remove it
#Next: i, is i in 'this'? Okay,  remove it
#Next: s, is s in 'this'? Okay, remove it
#Next: t, is t in 'this'? Okay, remove it
#Next: h, is h in 'this'? Okay, remove it
#Next: a, is a in 'this'? No, so, stop
#Ouput: at

#Using STRIP
c = 'thisthat'
print(c.strip("th"))
#Begin from both sides and repeat the steps from above; essentially, stripping from both sides.
#Using lstrip => isthat
#Now, using rstrip => istha
#Ouput: istha
```