# Get folder location for windows dynamically in python 3.5

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am creating a small script that removes unwanted browser trackers from the C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache location. The problem is I cant seem to get to AppData\Local.

when running this:

```
os.getenv('APPDATA')
```

I get this output: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming

I need to remove \Roaming so that i can get lower in the \Local tree. How do I dynamically get to the above location exclusively on windows 10 and 7 using python 3.5?

Comment: `LocalAppData`?

Comment: this may help you: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038824/how-do-i-remove-a-substring-from-the-end-of-a-string-in-python)

Comment: you can store the result of your code line in a var, then do: var.replace('Roaming', ''), then you can add the rest of the path needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you should be able to do this using `os.path.dirname`:

```
roaming = os.getenv('APPDATA')
app_data = os.path.dirname(roaming)
```

If you can't be sure to trust the environment variable, but are sure that the path you want will always end in `AppData`, then you can keep removing path parts until you find the part you want:

```
app_data = os.getenv('APPDATA')
while app_data and not app_data.endswith('AppData'):
    app_data = os.path.dirname(app_data)
```

Comment: @Schmuddi -- Sure.  For some reason, my fingers have an aversion to typing `dirname` and always want to type `basename` instead :-).

Comment: this is exactly what i needed Thanks

Comment: The variable is `LOCALAPPDATA` for the local application data. `APPDATA` is the roaming data, which is more generally used.

Comment: @eryksun -- Well, I guess that shows how much I know about Windows environments ;-)