# pandas how to create a boolean column based on other boolean columns in the df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`,

```
inv_date        inv_id
2017-10-01      100117
2018-04-02      040218
2018-05-06      060518
```

where `inv_date` is of `datetime` `dtype`, and `inv_id` is `str`; I want to convert `inv_id` into `datetime`, based on the following `formats`,

```
formats = {'%m%d%y': 6, '%d%m%y': 6}
L = [pd.to_datetime(s.str[:v], format=k, errors='coerce') for k, v in formats.items()]
df1 = pd.concat(L, axis=1, keys=[s.name + '_' + str(i) for i, s in zip(count(), L)])
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.where(x.between('2000-01-01', datetime.now())))
```

I want to create a boolean column `dummy_inv_id`, which is set to `True` if any of non-NaT converted `datetime` is within +/- 180 days of `inv_date`,

```
df1 = df1.assign(inv_date=df['inv_date'])
df1['inv_id_1'].between(df1['inv_date'] - Timedelta(180, unit='d'), df1['inv_date'] + Timedelta(180, unit='d'))
df1['inv_id_2'].between(df1['inv_date'] - Timedelta(180, unit='d'), df1['inv_date'] + Timedelta(180, unit='d'))
```

I am wondering how to consider all datetime columns (`inv_id_1` and `inv_id_2`) in `df1` collectively so if anyone is between `inv_date +/- 180 days`, then assign `true` to `df` for corresponding datetime;

so the results `df` look like,

```
inv_date        inv_id    dummy_inv_id
2017-10-01      100117    true
2018-04-02      040218    true
2018-05-06      060518    true
```

Comment: I get `a = df1['inv_id_1'].between(df1['inv_date'] - pd.Timedelta(180, unit='d'), df1['inv_date'] + pd.Timedelta(180, unit='d'))
b = df1['inv_id_2'].between(df1['inv_date'] - pd.Timedelta(180, unit='d'), df1['inv_date'] + pd.Timedelta(180, unit='d'))`

Comment: output is `print (a)
    0    True
    1    True
    2    True
    dtype: bool
    
    print (b)
    0    False
    1     True
    2     True
    dtype: bool`

Comment: So need `c = a | b` ?

Comment: @jezrael is it possible to put it all in one line considering how many formats defined, since the number of formats determines the number of converted date columns in `df1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.logical_or.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566):

```
a = df1['inv_id_1'].between(df1['inv_date'] - pd.Timedelta(180, unit='d'), df1['inv_date'] + pd.Timedelta(180, unit='d'))
b = df1['inv_id_2'].between(df1['inv_date'] - pd.Timedelta(180, unit='d'), df1['inv_date'] + pd.Timedelta(180, unit='d'))

c = [a,b]
df['dummy_inv_id'] = np.logical_or.reduce(c)
print (df)
    inv_date  inv_id  dummy_inv_id
0 2017-10-01  100117          True
1 2018-04-02   40218          True
2 2018-05-06   60518          True
```