# Removing file extension by using rstrip in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose that I have a list of song names

```
songlist = np.array(['1.mp3', '2.mp3','3.mp3'])
```

According to numpy documentation, there's a useful char function called `rstrip`:

> For each element in self, return a copy with the **trailing** characters
>   removed.

Since the file extension is exactly located in the trailing of the string, so I try using this `rstrip` to remove the file extensions

```
np.core.char.rstrip(songlist,'.mp3')
```

However, it gives me this following output

> array(['1', '2', ''], dtype='

What am I doing wrong here? How to use the `rstrip` function to remove the file extensions correctly?

Comment: `np.rstrip` second parameter `chars` is a set of characters that it removes, thus you will get same result if second parameter was '3pm.'

Comment: you can use [endswith or regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038824/how-do-i-remove-a-substring-from-the-end-of-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use numpy string functions:

`s = np.array([np.str.rpartition(s,'.mp3')[0] for s in songlist])`

You could also look at `partition` and `replace`

Answer (score 2):

I think numpy is not the best tool for working with strings. I'd use native python, personally.

```
songlist = np.array(['1.mp3', '2.mp3','3.mp3'])

# extract the part you want with split()
songlist = [s.split('.')[0] for s in songlist]
# could also just slice
# songlist = [s[:-4] for s in songlist]
```

Comment: You could still use the `np.char` functions: `np.vstack(np.char.split(songlist, '.'))[:,0]`.  But based on past timings, I don't expect any speed improvements compared to your list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

As @dgumo mentioned, `rstrip` removes characters irrespective of their order. To remove ".mp3" only,

```
[song.replace('.mp3' , '') for song in songlist]
```

Or if you are sure the string ends with .mp3

```
[song[:-4] if song.endswith('.mp3') else song for song in songlist]
```