# If a specific string, A, is present at the begining and/or end of a string B, how do we remove A from B?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

My question is similar, but different from the following:

[How do I remove a substring from the end of a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038824/how-do-i-remove-a-substring-from-the-end-of-a-string-in-python)

Suppose we have:

```
input = "baabbbbb_xx_ba_xxx_abbbbbba"
```

We want to want to keep everything except the `ba` at the end and `ba` at the beginning.

## 1) Direct `strip()` fails

`strip` treats the string as a set. That is, `strip` will remove the letters `a` and `b` appearing in any order. We want to only remove the characters `ba` if they appear in ***that*** exact order. Also, unlike `strip`, we want only zero or one copies removed from the end of the string. "x\n\n\n\n".strip() will remove many new-lines, not just one.

```
input = "baabbbbb_xx_ba_xxx_abbbbbba"
output = input.strip("ba")
print(output)
prints "_xx_ba_xxx_"
```

## 2) Direct `replace()` fails

```
input = "xx_ba_xxx"
output = input.replace("ba", "")
print(output)
# prints `xx__xxx`
```

Not cool; we only want to remove the sequence "`ba`" from the beginning and end of the string, not the middle.

## 3) Just nope

```
input = "baabbbbb_xx_ba_xxx_abbbbbba"
output = "ba".join(input.rsplit("ba", 1))
print(output)
# output==input
```

## Final Note

The solution must be general: a function accepting any two input strings, once of which might ***not*** be "ba". The undesired leading and trailing strings might contain "`.`", "`*`" and other characters not nice for use in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses basic hashing, however, be aware of hash collision.
Let me know if this helps you with your problem.

```
import functools


def strip_ed(pattern, string):
    # pattern is not a substring of string
    if len(pattern) > len(string):
        return -1

    base = 26
    # Hash codes for the beginning of the string
    string_hash_beginning = functools.reduce(lambda h, c: h * base + ord(c), string[:len(pattern)], 0)
    # Hash codes for the ending of the string
    string_hash_end = functools.reduce(lambda h, c: h * base + ord(c), string[-len(pattern):], 0)
    # Hash codes for the pattern
    pattern_hash = functools.reduce(lambda h, c: h * base + ord(c), pattern, 0)
    while True:
        if string_hash_beginning == string_hash_end and \
                string_hash_beginning == pattern_hash and \
                string[:len(pattern)] == pattern:
            return string[len(pattern):-len(pattern)]
        elif string_hash_beginning == pattern_hash and string[:len(pattern)] == pattern:
            return string[len(pattern):]
        elif string_hash_end == pattern_hash and string[-len(pattern):] == pattern:
            return string[:-len(pattern)]
        else:
            return string
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

```
def ordered_strip(whole, part):
    center = whole
    if whole.endswith(part):
        center = center[:-len(part)]
    if whole.startswith(part):
        center = center[len(part):]
    return center
```

Comment: You got one of your slices backward (and also you have a problem if `len(part) == 0`).

Comment: Anyway, this is pretty much just doing what you would to remove a substring from one end of a string, but doing it twice, so I'm not sure what value you were hoping to add here over the question you already linked.

Comment: `if whole.startswith(part): center = center[:-len(part)]` part should be `center = center[len(part):]`.

Comment: You've fixed the slice thing, but you still return `''` for `ordered_strip('asdf', '')`. Also, because you use `whole` instead of `center` for both starts/endswith checks, you return `''` for `ordered_strip('ababa', 'aba')`. Depending on what you're using this for, the second `''` result might be what you want, but it's different from how most Python string manipulation routines handle overlapping matches. (The first `''` result definitely isn't right.)