# Python3 strip() get unexpect result

Tags: python-3.x, encode, strip

It's a weird problem

```
to_be_stripped="D:\\Users\\UserKnown\\PycharmProjects\\ProjectKnown\\PT\\collections\\120"
```

And two strings below:

```
s1="D:\\Users\\UserKnown\\PycharmProjects\\ProjectKnown\\PT\\collections\\120\\[Content_Types].xml"
s2="D:\\Users\\UserKnown\\PycharmProjects\\ProjectKnown\\PT\\collections\\120\\_rels\.rels"
```

When I use the command below:

```
s1.strip(to_be_stripped)
s2.strip(to_be_stripped)
```

I get these outputs:

```
'[Content_Types].x'
'_rels\\.'
```

If I use `lstrip()`, they will be:

```
'[Content_Types].xml'
'_rels\\.rels'
```

Which is the right outputs.
**However**, if we replace all `Project Known` with `zeus_pipeline`:

```
to_be_stripped="D:\\Users\\UserKnown\\PycharmProjects\\zeus_pipeline\\PT\\collections\\120"
```

And:

```
s2="D:\\Users\\UserKnown\\PycharmProjects\\zeus_pipeline\\PT\\collections\\120\\_rels\.rels"
```

`s2.lstrip(to_be_stripped)`will be `'.rels'`

If I use `/` instead of `\\`, **nothing** goes wrong. I am wondering why this problem happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strip` isn't meant to remove full strings exactly. Rather, you give it a string, and every character in that string is removed from the start and of the string to be stripped.

In your case, the variable `to_be_stripped` contains the characters `m` and `l`, so those are stripped from the end of `s1`. However, it doesn't contain the character `x`, so the stripping stops there and no characters beyond that are removed.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038824/how-do-i-remove-a-substring-from-the-end-of-a-string-in-python). The accepted answer is probably more extensive than you need - I like another user's suggestion of using `replace` instead of `strip`. This would look like:

```
s1.replace(to_be_stripped, "")
```

Comment: I got this! Thank you for your help.

Comment: No worries. There's a lot of ways to do anything you might want to do, so it can be easy to pick the wrong method!