# Send multiple values from a tuple to a function

Tags: python, tuples

So i have a tuple with this structure:

```
tuple =   ('Art School', 'Berlin', 'John Morgan(School1-Ge/Berlin);Andrew Martin (School1-IT/Roma); Tom Jones(School1-USA/Chicago)')
```

Each person structure it's like this :

```
John,Morgan(School name-Country-GE/City-Berlin)
```

I need to get every person email address and for this i'm using a function where i sent the name of the person as a parameter.

```
def get_email_address(name):
    if name is not '':
        try:
            sql = sql1%name
            cur.execute(sql)
        except Exception as e :
            print()
        txt = str(cur.fetchone())
        email = txt[2:len(txt)-3]
        return email
    return ''
```

where `sql1="""select MAIL from email_table where NAME= '%s'"""`

```
and NAME = tuple[2]
```

When there is only one person in tuple[2] is working fine ,but when the number increase i only get the last person email address.

My question is how to send all values from the tuple[2] to the email function to get all persons email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split the string to multiple names. I think you can split it on the character ";". The modified code will be something like follows:

```
tuple =   ('Art School', 'Berlin', 'John Morgan(School1-Ge/Berlin);Andrew Martin (School1-IT/Roma); Tom Jones(School1-USA/Chicago)')
names_combined = tuple[2]
names_split = names_combined.split(";")
for name in names_split:
    print(name)
    get_email_address(name)
```

Comment: I tried your solution and also i wanted to put the results in a list. I had 2 persons in tuple [2] but for one of them i didn't get an email because that person left and it's  no longer in the table but the list looks like this :  ['john_morgan@gmail.com', '', '']  and also when i have only 1 person that no longer works i get ['', ''] . So everytime i get this ","   and i don't understand why.

Comment: I think you can use slicing,  for each email, you  can check the final character is "," email[-1]=="," and remove the final character by email = email[:,-1]

Comment: you can also refer to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038824/how-do-i-remove-a-substring-from-the-end-of-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting tuple[2]:

```
tuple[2].split(';')
```

It will give output as:

```
['John Morgan(School1-Ge/Berlin)', 'Andrew Martin (School1-IT/Roma)', ' Tom Jones(School1-USA/Chicago)']
```

Now a for loop can be used to iterate trough the elements of this list.