# rstrip() stripping more than it should in Python

Tags: python

```
k = '9\t10\t12314\t12\t13\t14\t'
print(k.rstrip('\t12\t13\t14\t'))
```

For this given code the output that I would've expected is:

`9       10      12314`

But the output that I obtain on running this code is:

`9       10`

Replacing 12314 with any sequence of integers from 1-4 leads to this same faulty output, but the moment it reaches an integer greater than 5 it stops stripping the string. For example if we added a 5 in between 12314:

```
k = '9\t10\t123514\t12\t13\t14\t'
print(k.rstrip('12\t13\t14\t'))
```

Leads to the output:

`9       10      1235`

An explanation of why this happens would be appreciated. I tried looking up the code for the rstrip() function but I didn't find anything useful, but that might just be because I don't dig through source code too often. Also, I have been able to recreate this in python 3.x as well as 2.x so as far as I know it isn't version-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you think .strip() is doing something different then it actually does.

.strip() and .rstrip() remove all characters on of the iterable you provide. This means:

```
"all my allmonds".strip("my all")
```

will leave only "onds" because strip will strip the following: " ", "a", "l", "m", "y" and **!not!** "my all" as you might have expected.

As for an solution, you can use regex.

Answer (score 3):

It's because `strip` function in Python try to strip every **"character(s)"** passed into the function.

For example:

```
> 'test1234'.rstrip('4')
test123                       # expected

> 'test1234'.rstrip('34')
test12                        # expected

> 'test1234'.rstrip('43')
test12                        # try to strip every `4` and `3`
```

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_ref_string_rstrip2

---

I think what you need is `removesuffix` which is available on Python 3.9 or above :)

```
> 'test1234'.removesuffix('34')
test12

> 'test1234'.removesuffix('43')
test12      # do nothing since string does not ends with `43`
```

See more about `removesuffix` [here](https://www.andreagrandi.it/2020/10/11/python39-introduces-removeprefix-removesuffix/).

But if you cannot go to Python 3.9 then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1038845/7930117) might help :)