# Remove trailing newline from the elements of a string list

Tags: python, list, strip

I have to take a large list of words in the form:

```
['this\n', 'is\n', 'a\n', 'list\n', 'of\n', 'words\n']
```

and then using the strip function, turn it into:

```
['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']
```

I thought that what I had written would work, but I keep getting an error saying:

> "'list' object has no attribute 'strip'"

Here is the code that I tried:

```
strip_list = []
for lengths in range(1,20):
    strip_list.append(0) #longest word in the text file is 20 characters long
for a in lines:
    strip_list.append(lines[a].strip())
```

Comment: Please explain why you are appending 0 to `strip_list` 19 times then appending your stripped lines. That code has a very bad smell about it. Also if you got that stuff from a file, you should be stripping it on the way in -- building a large list then bashing it into another large list is not a good idea.  Also 2, your code should not depend on knowing the length of the longest word/line. Step back a bit -- what are your trying to achieve? What will you do with `strip_list`?

Comment: Related [How to remove \n from a list element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3849509)

Answer (score 297, accepted):

You can either use a list comprehension

```
my_list = ['this\n', 'is\n', 'a\n', 'list\n', 'of\n', 'words\n']
stripped = [s.strip() for s in my_list]
```

or alternatively use `map()`:

```
stripped = list(map(str.strip, my_list))
```

In Python 2, `map()` directly returned a list, so you didn't need the call to list. In Python 3, the list comprehension is more concise and generally considered more idiomatic.

Comment: could I then just say stripped_list = map(str.strip, my_list)
and then print stripped_list to print this new list?

Comment: If you're using Python 2, note however, that `str.strip` only works if you're sure that the list does not contain unicode strings. If it can contain both 8-bit and unicode strings, use `lambda s: s.strip()` as mentioned above, or use the `strip` function which you can import from the `strings` module.

Comment: The Cito comment is actually the one that deserves the most rep. map and comprehension lists are not equivalent in OOP, because we are passe methods, not functions.

Comment: built in map function in the samaritan

Comment: Be aware of the following: If you are using Python 3.x and you want to return a list, you have to `list`, so that it's `list(map(str.strip, my_list))`. Also check that out: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-x/1303354#1303354).

Comment: For anyone having unicode error, this works for me: map(unicode.strip, my_list)

Comment: Very crisp and perfect answer. Works like a charm for me with python 2.7. Thanks a lot.

Comment: did not workat all, but ? [x.strip() for x in lst] did

Comment: @user7082181 In Python 3, `map()` returns an iterator, so you need to iterate over it to get the stripped lines – see the most upvoted comment above. I've also clarified this answer (which is almost ten years old by now).

Answer (score 130):

list comprehension?
`[x.strip() for x in lst]`

Answer (score 70):

You can use [lists comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
strip_list = [item.strip() for item in lines]
```

Or the [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
# with a lambda
strip_list = map(lambda it: it.strip(), lines)

# without a lambda
strip_list = map(str.strip, lines)
```

Comment: The lambda in the second version is overkill.

Comment: You can use the same approach to do whatever it is with the `0` values at the beginning of the list, too. Although I can't really imagine what it is you're trying to accomplish by putting them in the same result list...

Comment: In Python 3, the 3rd form "without a lambda" should be `strip_list = list(map(str.strip, lines))` as map() returns a map iterator. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: you can also use the same var? `lines = [item.strip() for item in lines]`

Answer (score 8):

This can be done using list comprehensions as defined in [PEP 202](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)

```
[w.strip() for w in  ['this\n', 'is\n', 'a\n', 'list\n', 'of\n', 'words\n']]
```

Comment: I was thinking of changing the name from `list` to `map` :)

Answer (score 3):

All other answers, and mainly about list comprehension, are great. But just to explain your error:

```
strip_list = []
for lengths in range(1,20):
    strip_list.append(0) #longest word in the text file is 20 characters long
for a in lines:
    strip_list.append(lines[a].strip())
```

`a` is a member of your list, not an index. What you could write is this:

```
[...]
for a in lines:
    strip_list.append(a.strip())
```

Another important comment: you can create an empty list this way:

```
strip_list = [0] * 20
```

But this is not so useful, as `.append` *appends* stuff to your list. In your case, it's not useful to create a list with defaut values, as you'll build it item per item when appending stripped strings.

So your code should be like:

```
strip_list = []
for a in lines:
    strip_list.append(a.strip())
```

But, for sure, the best one is this one, as this is exactly the same thing:

```
stripped = [line.strip() for line in lines]
```

In case you have something more complicated than just a `.strip`, put this in a function, and do the same. That's the most readable way to work with lists.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to remove just *trailing* whitespace, you could use [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip), which should be slightly more efficient than [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
>>> lst = ['this\n', 'is\n', 'a\n', 'list\n', 'of\n', 'words\n']
>>> [x.rstrip() for x in lst]
['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']
>>> list(map(str.rstrip, lst))
['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your list and simply replace `\n` with empty space `""` without appending it to the new list

```
main_list = ['this\n', 'is\n', 'a\n', 'list\n', 'of\n', 'words\n']

for i in range(0, len(main_list)):
    main_list[i] = main_list[i].replace("\n", "")
```

Using this method you can perform multilple replacements at the same time.
Replacing `\n` with empty space `""` and replacing `sample_text` string with the `""` for each element of the `main_list`

```
main_list = ['this\nsample_text', 'is\nsample_text', 'a\nsample_text', 'list\nsample_text', 'of\nsample_text', 'words\nsample_text']

for i in range(0, len(main_list)):
    main_list[i] = main_list[i].replace("\n", "").replace("sample_text", "")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my_list = ['this\n', 'is\n', 'a\n', 'list\n', 'of\n', 'words\n']
print([l.strip() for l in my_list])
```

Output:

```
['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']
```

Comment: same as other older answers