# Map function on string list printing memory location

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, strip, map-function

For my project I do some stuff and extract a specific line from the command line output and then insert it into a list. From there I export the list into a trainingfile for a learning algorithm to use later. The problem is when i pull the information off of the command line it pulls

```
"Number\n"
```

When i append the list to a text file it doesn't print

```
 Number, Number, Number
```

Instead it is printing

```
Number
Number
Number
```

It is applying the newline character and this is nearly useless to me. With some googling I found this link **[Strip all the elements of a string list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984169/using-strip-on-lists)** explaining what I thought was exactly what i needed to fix the problem. It strips out the newline character and turns the list into what i need for later use. EXCEPT for whatever reason it isn't working.

Here is my code

```
def exportlist(self):  
    file = open('Trainingfile.txt','a+')
    # i pass it into a variable since i ran into some odd errors if i try 
    # to apply the map function to self.vectorlist
    my_list= self.vectorlist      
    print(my_list)               # prints [ 'number\n', 'number\n'......]
    # WHAT THE ABOVE LINK AND OTHERS SAID SHOULD WORK
    strip_list= map(str.rstrip('\n'), my_list)  
    print(strip_list)            # prints "map object at 0x00000002C...."
    self.vectorlist = strip_list # test code 
    print(self.vectorlist)       # prints same as strip_list
    file.close()
```

I get similar results if i use chr.split instead of strip. 
Printing my_list prints the improperly formatted list.
printing the strip_list which is supposed to be the properly formatted list, prints what i think is a memory location " 0x0000000002C...." Everything i found online is telling me that it should not be printing this. It should be printing the properly formatted list. Does anyone know why this is happening? This happens everytime i use the map function. I have tried multiple methods to strip "\n" from my list but it always returns the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert your result into a list:

```
strip_list = list(map(str.rstrip('\n'), my_list))
```

In Python 3 `map()` returns a map object. This is an iterator. You can convert to a list by using `list()`  around it.

Comment: Just did that and I wouldnt say it crashes but it goes from printing instantly to running for 30 seconds and then giving me the error

     'str' object is not callable

Comment: @Sam: Because you shouldn't use `str` as a variable name, did you use `str` as a function after you **re-define it as a variable** again?

Comment: `print()` is slow. Just take all `print()` out. What error? Your question does not have any error message.

Comment: @Sam Your follow-up questions address different problems and are about code you don't show here. It would be better to create a new question that shows the relevant code and the error message. My answer here should solve the problem with `map()`.

Comment: computer crashed from something else so that's why it ran for 30 seconds. So ignore that problem.  @KevinGuan the only time I use 'str' is when i call 'map()'. What should I use instead of str?

Answer (score 0):

from Documentation...

```
Help on class map in module builtins:

class map(object)
 |  map(func, *iterables) --> map object
 |  
 |  Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from
 |  each of the iterables.  Stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.

class list(object)
 |  list() -> new empty list
 |  list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
```

So you have wrap your iterator with a list call to get the list, like :

```
list(map(f, list))
```