# How to strip unicode in a list

Tags: python, unicode

I want to strip unicode string from the list 
for example
 airports
[u'KATL',u'KCID']

expected output

[KATL,KCID]

Followed the below link

[Strip all the elements of a string list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984169/strip-all-the-elements-of-a-string-list)

Tried one of the solution

> > > my_list = ['this\n', 'is\n', 'a\n', 'list\n', 'of\n', 'words\n']
> > >
> > > map(str.strip, my_list)
> > >       ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']

got the following error

TypeError: descriptor 'strip' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want to remove the `u` from your strings?! You're barking up the wrong tree then, it's not something you need to remove, it's only indicating that you're dealing with `unicode` strings, not byte strings. That is not a problem you need to solve.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, I strongly suggest you switch to Python 3, which treats Unicode strings as first-class citizens (all strings are Unicode strings, but they are called `str`).

But if you have to make it work in Python 2, you can strip `unicode` strings with `unicode.strip` (if your strings are true Unicode strings):

```
>>> lst = [u'KATL\n', u'KCID\n']
>>> map(unicode.strip, lst)
[u'KATL', u'KCID']
```

If your `unicode` strings are limited to ASCII subset, you can convert them to `str` with:

```
>>> lst = [u'KATL', u'KCID']
>>> map(str, lst)
['KATL', 'KCID']
```

Note that this conversion will fail for non-ASCII strings. To encode Unicode codepoints as a `str` (string of bytes), you have to choose your encoding algorithm (usually UTF-8) and use `.encode()` method on your strings:

```
>>> lst = [u'KATL', u'KCID']
>>> map(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'), lst)
['KATL', 'KCID']
```

Comment: still  I am not able to convert  124                     import pdb
 125                     pdb.set_trace()
 126                     # Strip all the elements of a string list
 127                     map(unicode.strip, airports)                                                                      output is 
(Pdb++) pp airports
[u'KATL']

Comment: I don't see any error message but I just see that list has still the same unicode

Comment: You actually want to convert unicodes to strings, try the second example from the answer, `map(str, lst)`.

Answer (score 4):

The only reliable to convert a unicode string to a byte string is to *encode* it into an acceptable encoding (ascii, Latin1 and UTF8 are most common one). By definition, UTF8 is able to encode any unicode character, but you will find non ascii chars in the string, and the size in byte will no longer be the number of (unicode) characters. Latin1 is able to represent most of west european languages characters in with a 1 byte per character relation, and ascii is the set of characters that are always correctly represented.

If you want to be able to process strings containing characters not representable in the choosen charset, you can use the parameter `errors='ignore'` to just remove them or `errors='replace'` to replace them with a *replacement character*, often `?`.

So if I have correctly understood your requirement, you could translate the list of unicode string into a list of byte strings with:

```
[ x.encode('ascii', errors='replace') for x in my_list ]
```

Answer (score 2):

A listcomp seems the simplest solution:

```
[s.strip() for s in my_list]
```

If you're keen to use a map, I'd use a lambda to get the object's own personal `strip` function rather than demanding that it be the `strip` that's delivered by one particular library.

```
map(lambda s: s.strip(), my_list)
```