# How to split list elements to a line separated by space

Tags: python, regex, scripting

I have a list in python as :

```
values = ['Maths\n', 'English\n', 'Hindi\n', 'Science\n', 'Physical_Edu\n', 'Accounts\n', '\n']
print("".join(values))
```

I want output should be as :-

```
Subjects: Maths English Hindi Science Physical_Edu Accounts
```

I am new to Python, I used join() method but unable to get expected output.

Comment: Thank you for your question, but please update it to show the code you have written so far.

Comment: I used below code to print list elements
print("".join(values))
Output is :- 
Maths
English
Hindi
Science
Physical_Edu
Accounts
Plus Two Line Space
But I want ourput in a single line only separated by space.

Comment: What's your code and actual output? Since there's "\n" in your list, there should be multilines in your output if you do not trim or replace "\n".

Comment: Ok, I'll update the question myself with this new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strip()` each element of the string and then `join()` with a `space` in between them.

```
a = ['Maths\n', 'English\n', 'Hindi\n', 'Science\n', 'Physical_Edu\n', 'Accounts\n', '\n']
print("Subjects: " +" ".join(map(lambda x:x.strip(), a)))
```

Output:

```
Subjects: Maths English Hindi Science Physical_Edu Accounts
```

As pointed out by @miindlek, you can also achieve the same thing, by using **`map(str.strip, a)`** in place of `map(lambda x:x.strip(), a))`

Comment: Didn't downvote. But why do you use a lambda function for calling another function

Comment: @miindlek Thank you for guiding me.

Answer (score 6):

You could map the `str.strip`function to every element in the list and join them afterwards.

```
values = ['Maths\n', 'English\n', 'Hindi\n', 'Science\n', 'Physical_Edu\n', 'Accounts\n', '\n']

print("Subjects:", " ".join(map(str.strip, values)))
```

Comment: You need to add space between items, your code will print them without it

Comment: You could even use `.rstrip()` as the newline characters only appear on the right side of the string (+1 though).

Comment: @Jan right! To be more explicit, you could even use `.rstrip("\n")`. But I guess `str.strip` is perfectly fine in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression approach:

```
import re

lst = ['Maths\n', 'English\n', 'Hindi\n', 'Science\n', 'Physical_Edu\n', 'Accounts\n', '\n']

rx = re.compile(r'.*')
print("Subjects: {}".format(" ".join(match.group(0) for item in lst for match in [rx.match(item)])))
# Subjects: Maths English Hindi Science Physical_Edu Accounts
```

But better use `strip()` (or even better: `rstrip()`) as provided in other answers like:

```
string = "Subjects: {}".format(" ".join(map(str.rstrip, lst)))
print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984169/strip-all-the-elements-of-a-string-list) to strip the newlines and join them using:

```
joined_string = " ".join(stripped_array)
```