# Python3 trim all data from associative array

Tags: python, python-3.x, trim

I'm using Python3 and I tried all way of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984169/strip-all-the-elements-of-a-string-list) but no one solution works. If I do this way `list(map(str.strip, my_list))` I lost all my keys because `list()` return just values accessible just with indice.

So I decided to trim manually with `.strip()` all my data but it will not work for `NoneType` data. I don't want to do 30 conditions...

```
if str:
   str.strip(' ')
```

So do you have a solution to trim all str value in my associative array ? My array can content None, Int and String.

Comment: Could you give an example of your input? We can only presume that by "_associative array_" you mean "_dict_".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that when you say "associative array" you actually mean a Python dict.

```
>>> d = { 'a': 'foo\n', 'b': 3, 'c': None }
>>> cleaned = { k: v.strip() if isinstance(v, str) else v for k,v in d.items() }
>>> cleaned
{'b': 3, 'a': 'foo', 'c': None}
```

Comment: It works thank you so much. When I search `Python trim dictionary` I can find lot of answers too. But I'll not delete my question because if someone try to search the solution with the `associative array` term like me.