# How to put a file.txt into more than one list in python

Tags: python, list, file, readlines

I am trying to put my `file.txt` into a list and then each index into different lists while all the lists remain in the initial list. I have been able to add it into a single list so far.

Here's my code:

```
with open("evenements.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as evenement:
    liste_evenement = evenement.readlines()
    print(liste_evenement)
```

I want my code to return :

```
[['index_1'],['index_2'], ...]
```

Do I have to use a `for` loop? or even a `while`? I'm a little confused because of the `\n` at the end of every line of my `evenements.txt`, so if you could help me with that because I am familiar with `.strip()` when I use it on a string but its not working on a list.

EDIT : here's a sample of what i need to do now :

My code is now returning :

```
[['Musique/Shawn Phillips/2018-08-24/2018-08-24'], "Musique/L'avenue Royale fête l'été!/2018-08-25/2018-08-25"], 'Musique/Perséides musicales/2018-08-03/2018-08-03'], 'Musique/Gaétan Leclerc chante Félix et…/2018-08-17/2018-08-17']]
```

What i need to do now is that i need to add a " for every '/' in my code so a " between Musique and shawn and another one between phillips and 2018, except between the Year/Month/Day (just look at the result down below. Keep in mind that this is just a part of the code and my list actually contains 160 index.

so heres the result that im looking for :

```
[['Danse', 'Samedi de danser...', 202, 202],
```

Comment: What is _each index_? You have not mentioned any indexes.

Comment: Well, the evenement.readlines() returns a list of my evenements.txt right ? So i want each index of my list to become a list of its own while they remain in the initiat list so it would be something like that : [['index 1'],['index 2']]

Comment: so does the file have a filename/path per file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip all the elements of a string list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984169/strip-all-the-elements-of-a-string-list)

Comment: Please include a sample of your file and the expected output. Is your file called file.txt or evenements.txt?

Comment: @AGNGazer Yes thanks for the link, but the main issue is about the file tho!

Comment: Your first sentence: _"I am trying to put my `file.txt` into a list and then each index into different lists while all the lists remain in the initial list."_ is absolutely confusing. I can't figure it out. As suggested by @DYZ, an example of data and desired output would greatly help.

Comment: Where are indices in `[['index_1'],['index_2'], ...]` supposed to come from? Are these part of each line? Why there is only one index per innermost list???

Comment: How about providing an example file content and desired output based on _that_ example file.

Comment: Can we get a sample of the text you are opening

Answer (score -1):

You can use slicing and a comprehension for that:

```
with open("yourfile", "r") as f:
    number_of_lists = 4
    lists = [f[i::number_of_lists] for i in range(number_of_lists)]
```

<strike>Not sure if you can slice a file directly; if not make f a list with all lines in it.</strike> as has been pointed out in the comments you can't directly but can use `itertools.islice` to do so. Or make a list

This takes every nth element from the file and offsets the start of this nth with n.

EDIT: Just read your comment, if you want each line to be a list:

```
with open("file" ,"r") as f:
    list = [[x] for x in f]
```

EDIT2: to strip newlines:

```
with open("yourfile", "r") as f:
    number_of_lists = 4
    lists = [[x.rstrip("/n") for x in f[i::number_of_lists]] for i in range(number_of_lists)]
```

Comment: You cannot slice a file object directly, but you can use `itertools.islice` to do so.

Comment: @SV-97 thanks ! i didnt know i could do that. ill keep that in mind !

Comment: @SV-97 but is this possible to also stack another for loop to remove the '\n' like AGN Gazer suggested

Comment: Added a version that strips newlines

Comment: @SV-97 i always get the error message  '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Oxynor IIRC that happens if you try to slice it directly. Put a `content = [x for line in f]` before the lists Line and change it so that it slices from content instead of f. Or see the crossed out section in my comment