# Issues reading and writing txt files line by line

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

The script is written using PyQt4.10.1 and Python2.7

I have been working on a simple tool to do allow a user to search for paths and then save them out to a config file for another program to read later. If there is already a config file then the script reads it and displays the existing paths for the user to edit or add to. I wrote a gui to make it as user friendly as possible. There are a couple issues I am having with it.

First, when I read in the config file I am using the following code:

```
try:
    self.paths = open(configFile, "r")
    self.data = self.paths.readlines()
    self.paths.close()
except:
    self.data = None

if self.data is not None:
        for line in self.data:
            print line
            #self.listDelegate is the model for my QListView
            self.listDelegate.insertRows(0, 1, line)
```

When I do that I get the following in my gui:

[image: This is how it looks when you first input the data]

This (above) is how it looks when you first input the data (before the data is saved and then reopened)

[image: This is how the data looks after the config file is saved and then reopened]

This (above) is how the data looks after the config file is saved and then read back in (note the extra space below the path).

The config file is only read in when the script is first opened. 
the following is how the config file looks when it is written out.

```
C:\Program Files
C:\MappedDrives
C:\NVIDIA
```

Now all of that wouldnt be a big deal but when I open the config file to edit it with this tool then the extra space in the gui is read as another line break. so the config file is then printed as:

```
C:\Program Files

C:\MappedDrives

C:\NVIDIA
```

Then the problem just gets bigger and bigger every time I edit the file.

This issue leads me to the second issue (which I think may be the culprit). When I write the lines from the gui to the config file I use the following code:

```
    rowCount = self.listDelegate.rowCount()

    if rowCount > 0:

        myfile = open(configFile, 'w')

        for i in range(rowCount):
            myfile.write(str(self.listDelegate.index(i).data(role = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole).toPyObject()))
            myfile.write("\n")

        myfile.close()
```

I am assuming that the issue with the extra line breaks is because I am adding the line breaks in manually. The problem is that I need each path to be on its own line for the config file to be usable later. I don't have a lot of experience writing out text files and everyone says that the easiest way to write them out line by line is to add in the line breaks by hand. If anyone has any better ideas I would love to hear them.

Sorry for the long winded explanation. If I am not being clear enough please tell me and I will try to explain myself better.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your screenshots don't display, so I'm not clear what problems you are having

Comment: And btw: Asking a question with a minimal example is easier to answer and more helpful for others finding this question later. In this case you could have replaced the user interface code with a simple list and you would have gotten the same result.

Comment: I apologize for the specific question. I will try to be more abstract and generalized in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that every time you read the file the line break remains at the end of the line. From the [description of readline](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> `f.readline()` reads a single line from the file; a newline character (`\n`) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline.

If you try

```
self.paths = open(configFile, "r")
self.data  = self.paths.readlines()
for line in self.data:
    print repr(line)
```

which prints the representation of every line as python code you will get something like

```
'C:\\Program Files\n'
'C:\\MappedDrives\n'
'C:\\NVIDIA\n'
```

As you later insert further newlines the easiest fix is probably to [remove the trailing newline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3849699/371137):

```
for line in self.data:
    strippedLine = line.rstrip('\n')
```