# Problems removing \n from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have looked up various solutions that make sense, and tried to implement them in my code.  When I print out the list I'm still receiving the number with a newline character.  Here is my code:

```
infile = open(r"C:\Users\rr205951\Documents\nums.txt", "r")
    numList = infile.readlines()
    print("Before: ", numList)

    for num in numList:
        num = num.rstrip('\n')

    print("After: ", numList)
```

When I run the above code it still returns this following:

```
Before:  ['15\n', '4\n', '3\n', '25\n', '2000\n', '328\n', '20\n', '9\n', '18\n', '4333\n']
After:  ['15\n', '4\n', '3\n', '25\n', '2000\n', '328\n', '20\n', '9\n', '18\n', '4333\n']
```

Comment: `numList = [i.strip() for i in infile.readlines()]`

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30881893/4099593) answer. It covers more than 5 ways of doing your job

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually modifying numList. You could do a one-liner list comprehension like so:

`#read your lines as you did, but add the following after.`
`numList = [num.strip() for num in numList]`

Comment: This is good because it explains why OPs code is not working as desired.

Answer (score 0):

numList = map(lambda s: s.strip(), numList)