# Strip \n from list created from txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, strip

I am self studying Python and give myself random tasks to work towards and I am trying to remove the \n from the end of each element in a list that I have created from a text file?

I have seen:
[How to remove \n from a list element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849509/how-to-remove-n-from-a-list-element)

However applying this doesn't seem to be working for me and I am not quite sure why? Is anyone able to advise how to strip \n from the end of each element?

```
word =[]
finalList =[]

#Problem area
dictionary = open ('FILELOCATION\dictionary.txt', 'r')
for line in dictionary.readlines():
    word.append([line])
    for i in line.split():
        finalList[-1].append(i)

#Looping over the list
n = 0
while n < 25:
    print (finalList[n])
    n += 1
```

Comment: Why are you printing `word`s, if you store the result in `finalList`?

Comment: I am printing them to check that they are in fact stored, I want to draw from them to open a pdf document that is encrypted - task from a book that I am reading (Automate the boring stuff).

I can provide that code on here if you need it, but it is a way off from being correct.

Just realised what you mean't that was supposed ot be changed

Comment: you can try `line.strip()` or `line.rstrip('\n')`

Comment: Thanks wikunia exactly what I needed to get it to work!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
final_list = []
with open("accounts.txt","r") as my_file:
    first_list = my_file.readlines() 
    for i in first_list: 
        final_list.append(i.strip())
```

change it to suit your needs, this removes any `\n`.