# Python remove line breaks

Tags: python

I'm reading output from program like this

```
test_output = test_run.communicate(input=str.encode(input))[0]
output = test_output .decode('utf-8').strip()
```

and if program returns new line like this

```
>>> a
>>> b
```

it reads it like this(with `repr()`)

```
>>> 'a\r\nb'
```

I tried removing line breaks with

```
output.replace(r"\r\n","")
```

but it's not working, if I print it like regular string it returns

```
>>> a
>>> b
```

and repr()

```
>>> 'a\r\nb'
```

How can I remove \r\n from my string?

Comment: Also see [How can I remove (chomp) a newline in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/275018) and [How to remove \n from a list element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3849509)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a regexp, the regexp doesn't do what you think it does:

```
>>> 'a\r\nb'.replace('\r\n', '')
'ab'
```

i.e. just remove the `r` in `replace(r'\r\n', '')`