# String formatting in selenium/python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I ran selenium chromedriver and did scrap some text from website. Now the problem is text string is not in proper format.
The string in the code is: `selectDescription.text`
code:

```
for link in links:
    print "Navigating to link" + link
    browser.get(link)
    try:
        selectDescription = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='md'])[2]")
        try:
            data['description'].append(selectDescription.text)
        except KeyError:
            data['description'] = [selectDescription.text]
    except NoSuchElementException:
        try:
            data['description'].append("")
        except KeyError:
            data['description'] = [""]
        continue
```

For example:

this is
is bad

text

I want it to be formatted into: this is bad text

How can I do that? Do I have to remove new line before I insert it into my array? I did try searching, but since I am new to python, some of the stuff is just getting over my head. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Should I be using replace method?

Comment: could you share a snippet of your code, as I don't know in which array you are trying to save it.

Comment: I edited the question. It might help some one else too :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove \n from a list element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849509/how-to-remove-n-from-a-list-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by calling `"some string with \n linebreaks".replace("\n","")`

Comment: Yes Sebastian, I was able to find this by my own after searching for an hour!! lol. Sometimes simple things are difficult to comprehend, especially when learning a new language. Thanks, your answer does work perfectly in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to ask this question, but after simply using the replace function I was able to resolve this problem.
The code might help some newbie trying their hands on python:

```
string.replace('\n', ' ')
```

In my scenario I did: `selectDescription.text.replace('\n', ' ')`
Thanks again :)