# remove "\n" in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove \n in my list, but unfortunately my code does not work.

```
mylist = ['\nHello', 'This', 'Is A', 'List']

for items in mylist:
    if "\n" in items:
        items.replace("\n", "")

print(mylist)
```

Is there a way to remove a letter in a string, that is in a list?

Comment: `replace` returns a new string, but you're not assigning it to anything.

Comment: you never assigned the result of `items.replace("\n", "")`

Comment: You are probably looking for `items.strip()`

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think that's the best dupe tbh. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290762/cant-modify-list-elements-in-a-loop-python/19290848) works with looping through a list (the top answer isn't great). The result still has to be assigned back to a list item and your dupe doesn't (I don't think?) cover that

Comment: @k-doe try `mylist = [item.strip('\n') for item in mylist]`

Comment: more accurate dupe may be [How to remove \n from a list element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849509/how-to-remove-n-from-a-list-element)

Comment: @davedwards item.strip('\n') will strip any occurence of "\" and "n", that's probably not what is expected. in order to strip the sequence of "\" and "n", you need to use `str.replace('\n','')`. Something as follows e.g.: `mylist = [e.replace('\n', '') for e in mylist]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use map

```
mylist = ['\nHello', 'This', 'Is A', 'List']
list(map(str.strip,mylist))
```