# Is there a way to remove "\n" in a list

Tags: python, directory

I have a list of various directories that are saved in a .txt file, and I use file.readlines() to put all the lines in that .txt file into a list.

Is there a way I could filter out the "\n" at the end of every entry?

One line in this .txt folder would look something like this

```
D:/Music/Song.mp3\n
```

I am basically taking the entries from the .txt file and putting them into a Tkinter ListBox so the user can select their song from that ListBox.

Comment: Use the rstrip() function, https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.rstrip

Comment: @user590028 it appears I cannot use this on a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.replace()` method

```
string_list = [
    "D:/Music/Song.mp3\n",
    "hello world\n"
]

new_string_list = [string.replace("\n","") for string in string_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `.read().splitlines()` instead of `.readlines()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's built-in strip function, which removes the leading whitespace. For example, after you read in the file:

```
txtinput = D:/Music/Song.mp3\n
txtinput = txtinput.strip() # This returns the required file path without the trailing new line
```

Similarly, you can see [How to remove \n from a list element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849509/how-to-remove-n-from-a-list-element) for more info

For more info about the strip function: 
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
for line in file:
    directory = line.strip()
```

instead of using the `readline()` method.

with `.strip()` you get the line without the `\n`