# How to remove stray newline and tab characters from string using Python RE

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a problem with a Python string. Given a Python string with escape characters such as:

```
"good \nand bad and\n\t not great and awesome"
```

I want to split this into an array on the `and`s, while also removing the stray `\n`'s and `\t`'s, such as below:

```
["good", "bad", "not great", "awesome"]
```

Is it possible to perform this in a single line with `re.split()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Comment: Followed by [``How to remove \n from a list element?``](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3849519/4985099)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex split approach.  We can try splitting on `\s+and\s+`, which will target `and` surrounded by whitespace on both sides.  Note that tabs and newlines are whitespace characters and are included by `\s`.

```py
inp = "good \nand bad and\n\t not great and awesome"
parts = re.split(r'\s+and\s+', inp)
print(parts)  # ['good', 'bad', 'not great', 'awesome']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out.

```
s = "good \nand bad and\n\t not great and awesome"
s = s.replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
s_list = s.split('and')
```