# Failed ping request in Python script

Tags: python-2.7, ping

I have a python script that want to ping a few (quite a few!) hosts. I have set this up to read the contents of a hosts.txt file as the hosts to ping in the script. The odd thing is that I am recieving the following error, for the first few addresses (no matter what they are):

```
Ping request could not find host 66.211.181.182. Please check the name and try again.
```

I have included the address shown above at twice (within the file) and it attempts a ping. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong - I am a python newbie, so be gentle.

---

Here is my script:

```py
import subprocess

hosts_file = open("hosts.txt","r")
lines = hosts_file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    ping = subprocess.Popen(
        ["ping", "-n", "1",line],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )
    out, error = ping.communicate() 
    print out
    print error
hosts_file.close()
```

Here is my hosts.txt file:

```
66.211.181.182
178.236.5.39
173.194.67.94
66.211.181.182
```

And here are the results from the above test:

```
Ping request could not find host 66.211.181.182
. Please check the name and try again.


Ping request could not find host 178.236.5.39
. Please check the name and try again.


Ping request could not find host 173.194.67.94
. Please check the name and try again.



Pinging 66.211.181.182 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 66.211.181.182:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss)
```

Comment: @EliAcherkan, that makes sense I suppose... When I was testing this reading part out, and I simply printed the lines, it break the lines. How would I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `line` variable contains a linebreak at the end (except for the last line of the file). From the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> `f.readline()` reads a single line from the file; a newline character (`\n`) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline.

You need to strip the `\n` before calling `Popen`: [How can I remove (chomp) a newline in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-newline-in-python)

Comment: That's the ticket!!! - I added "line = line.strip()" to strip all white space from both sides rather than just a new line. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Few comments:

1. Using readlines() is highly not recommended as it will load the entire file into memory.
2. I suggest using Generator in order to perform rstrip on each line and then pinging the server.
3. No need to use file.close - you can use with statement that does it for you

Your code should look like this:

```
import subprocess
def PingHostName(hostname):
    ping=subprocess.Popen(["ping","-n","1",hostname],stdout=subprocess.PIPE
                  ,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out,err=ping.communicate();
    print out
    if err is not None: print err

with open('C:\\myfile.txt') as f:
    striped_lines=(line.rstrip() for line in f)
    for x in striped_lines: PingHostName(x)
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback... couple of questions... 

what is generator... did you use it?

Comment: Generator are objects generated on the fly with lazy evaluation.
when you use generators to go over a list you don't actually create the list and iterates over it, every item in created on the fly. 
you can read more about them in http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators
and yes I'm using generators here 
(line.rstrip() for line in f) returns a generator object

Comment: thanks for the response... I have seen generators mentioned in over posts but didn't really understand the descriptions I read.. the one you have provided is very helpful. I'll try this code out, and see about using over generators over the weekend. Thanks

P.S. I would upvote your answer but don't have a enough reputation (or whatever it is called)

Comment: It OK :) you can just accept this answer. Hope it was helpful