# When reading from line returns newline - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python script to generate some code by reading from a file. However it does not work as expected.

Code:

```
with open('continent.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print "text ", line ," here"
```

Results

$ python ContinentCode.py

```
text  North America
here
text  South America
here
text  Central America
```

Desired

```
text  North America here
text  South America here
text  Central America here
```

Comment: It is because the lines you're printing contain new line characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the [`.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.strip#str.strip) method on `line`.

```
with open('continent.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print "text ", line.strip('\r\n') ," here"
```

Note the argument to strip specifies what characters to remove. By default `.strip()` removes spaces and tabs as well... not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print "text ", line.strip() ," here"
```

More info about strip [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip)

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems equivalent to one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-newline-in-python).

Summarizing the above thread, you can use `print "text ", line.rstrip("\n"), " here"`. line.rstrip("\n") will return remove any "\n" contained in the string `line`.

Or you could use `for line in fp.splitlines()`. .splitlines() returns a list of the lines WITHOUT newline characters. Personally, I'm a fan of splitlines. If you want, you can do something like
`lines = fp.splitlines()
for line in lines:
    [code goes here]`