# Raw_input using python 2.7

Tags: python

This is my function:

```
def mainMenu():
    print " Do you want to send a message(send) or add a name to the database(add) or exit the program(exit)?"
    answer = raw_input()
    print answer
    if answer is "send":
        sendMessage()
    elif answer is "add":
        addName()
    elif answer is "exit":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print "Sorry, '%s' is not a valid input. Please use one 'send', 'add', or 'exit'" %answer
```

No matter what I enter the result in the `else` statement. The only thing I can really thing it is would be a problem with `raw_input()`.

Here's a screenshot from the shell. The syntax highlighting is because I'm using sublimeREPL and it just does that, doesn't affect the code at all:

[image: program output]

I've tested all the functions that are called and they work fine individually

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/275018/

Comment: @Nemo: `raw_input()` doesn't include the newline, no.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Whoops. Not particularly "raw", then, is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing `is` with `==`.

For example:

```
In [1]: answer = raw_input()
arst

In [2]: answer
Out[2]: 'arst'

In [3]: answer == 'arst'
Out[3]: True

In [4]: answer is 'arst'
Out[4]: False
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I thought "is" was the same as "==" in python, but I guess there's some slight difference

Comment: "is" asks if two objects are the same object. "==" asks if two objects are equivalent. "is" really is just comparing the memory address and "==" just compares what is in that address. hope that clears it up.

Comment: Whoops, that's what I get for not paying attention to the changing sort order! I edited your answer instead of mine, sowwy.

Comment: So basically while two things may look the same they are stored separately in memory and are then not the same object. Very cool, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are using *identity tests* to compare strings. Users cannot possibly create the exact same string object when entering text; they create *new* string objects, with the same value contained, instead.

Don't use `is`, use `==` to test for *equality*; different objects with the same value:

```
if answer == "send":
    sendMessage()
elif answer == "add":
    addName()
elif answer == "exit":
    sys.exit()
```

See [Understanding Python's "is" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator).

Comment: Related to your previous answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator    ;)

Comment: awesome, thanks for the explanation! Switching it worked but I was wondering why it wouldn't be the same, that makes sense.

Comment: @Zulu: Thanks for saving me from searching! :-)