# how to remove \n from a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code for finding the speed of cars, when it runs it leaves a line between the printed `distance(dist)` and the speed

I have looked at how to remove the `\n` from the end but all of them that I've seen and tried have made it print out the word `dist` and not the number in the variable:

```
for line in open ('data.txt','r'):
    z,x,y,dist=line.rsplit(",")
    print(z)
    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(dist)
    speed = int(dist)/(int(y)-int(x))
    print(speed)
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-newline-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Lines read from a file include the line separators. You can use [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove it:

```
z, x, y, dist = line.rstrip().split(',')
```

This will remove *all* whitespace (spaces, tabs, line separators, etc.) from the end of the line before splitting the line by comma.

Your file format is perhaps more easily read with the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('data.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        z, x, y, dist = map(int, row)
        print(z)
        print(x)
        print(y)
        print(dist)
        speed = dist / (y - x)
        print(speed)
```