# unwanted newline in python .write

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem with `write()` in python, here is my code:

```
b=open("/home/thanasis/Dropbox/NoA/CasJobs/statistics_CI/filters.txt",'r')
a=open("/home/thanasis/Dropbox/NoA/CasJobs/statistics_CI/queries_CI.txt",'w')

for line in b:
    temp=line
    detector,filters=temp.split(",")

    a.write("SELECT MATCHID,AVG(CI) AS CI_AV into mydb.CI_%s_%s"  %(detector,filters))
    a.write("from detailedcatalog \n where Detector = '%s' and Filter= '%s'" %(detector,filters))
    a.write("GROUP BY MATCHID\ngo\n")

    a.close()
```

and the output is the following:

```
SELECT MATCHID,AVG(CI) AS CI_AV into mydb.CI_ACS/WFC_F625W
from detailedcatalog 
where Detector = 'ACS/WFC' and Filter= 'F625W
'GROUP BY MATCHID
go
```

The problem is that the `'` character jumps to the next line. I've tried all kind of different ways to write it. Any suggestions?

Comment: `filters.strip()` will take away any leading or trailing whitespace. then you have to put in a `\n` explicitly when you need it

Comment: thanks it worked! but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines read from a file have a terminated newline.  Use `.strip()` to remove leading and trailing white space before processing:

```
>>> temp  # example data
'1,2,3\n'
>>> temp.split(',')
['1', '2', '3\n']            # newline is still present.
>>> temp.strip().split(',')
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `filters` has the newline character from the text file.  You are actually seeing this in your first `write`:

```
SELECT MATCHID,AVG(CI) AS CI_AV into mydb.CI_ACS/WFC_F625W <- newline here from filters
from detailedcatalog
```

The solution is to use [`strip` or one of its variants to remove the newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-newline-in-python).  Once you use `strip` you will want to add a newline (`\n`) at the end of the first `write` if you intend for a newline to be there.