# How to check if \n is in a string

Tags: python, string, substring

I want to remove `\n` from a string if it is in a string.
I have tried:

```
slashn = str(chr(92))+"n"
if slashn in newString:
        newerString = newString.replace(slashn,'')
        print(newerString)
else:
    print(newString)
```

Assume that newString is a word that has `\n` at the end of it. E.g. `text\n`.

I have also tried the same code except slash equals to `"\\"+"n"`.

Comment: This is almost certainly Python, retagging.

Comment: Are you looking for a newline or a backslash + `n`?

Comment: Are you attempting to remove a newline character (`\n`) or the slash plus letter N sequence (`\\n`)? Do you clearly understand the difference between both?

Comment: `newString.remove('\n')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-newline-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.replace()` but with raw string literals:

```
newString = r"new\nline"
newerString = newString.replace(r"\n", "")
```

If you put a `r` right before the quotes enclosing a string literal, it becomes a raw string literal that does not treat any backslash characters as special escape sequences.

Example to clarify raw string literals (output is behind the `#>` comments):

```
# Normal string literal: single backslash escapes the 'n' and makes it a new-line character.
print("new\nline")  
#> new
#> line

# Normal string literal: first backslash escapes the second backslash and makes it a 
# literal backslash. The 'n' won't be escaped and stays a literal 'n'.
print("new\\nline")
#> new\nline

# Raw string literal: All characters are taken literally, the backslash does not have any
# special meaning and therefore does not escape anything.
print(r"new\nline")
#> new\nline

# Raw string literal: All characters are taken literally, no backslash has any
# special meaning and therefore they do not escape anything.
print(r"new\\nline")
#> new\\nline
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strip() of a string. Or strip('\n'). `strip` is a builtin function of a string. 
Example:

```
>>>
>>>
>>> """vivek
...
... """
'vivek\n\n'
>>>
>>> """vivek
...
... """.strip()
'vivek'
>>>
>>> """vivek
...
... \n"""
'vivek\n\n\n'
>>>
>>>
>>> """vivek
...
... \n""".strip()
'vivek'
>>>
```

Look for the `help` command for a string builtin function `strip` like this:

```
>>>
>>> help(''.strip)
Help on built-in function strip:

strip(...)
    S.strip([chars]) -> string or unicode

    Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
    whitespace removed.
    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
    If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping

>>>
```

Comment: Looks like the OP does not want the newline character but a literal `\n` (backslash character plus n character) to be removed from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
string_here.rstrip('\n')
```

To remove the newline.

Comment: I see. I needed to add the character to be stripped.

Comment: Looks like the OP does not want the newline character but a literal `\n` (backslash character plus n character) to be removed from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `strip()`

```
your_string.strip("\n")  # removes \n before and after the string
```

Comment: Looks like the OP does not want the newline character but a literal `\n` (backslash character plus n character) to be removed from the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the newline from the *ends* of a string, I'd use .strip(). If no arguments are given then it will remove whitespace characters, this includes newlines (\n).

Using .strip():

```
if newString[-1:-2:-1] == '\n': #Test if last two characters are "\n"
    newerString = newString.strip()
    print(newerString)
else:
    print(newString)
```

[Another .strip() example (Using Python 2.7.9)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e8bU.png)

Also, the newline character can simply be represented as "\n".

Comment: Looks like the OP does not want the newline character but a literal `\n` (backslash character plus n character) to be removed from the string.

Answer (score -1):

```
Text="test.\nNext line."
print(Text)
```

Output:::: `test.\nNextline"`

This is because the element is stored in double inverted commas.In such cases next line will behave as text enclose in string.