# Executing statement inside if block is not printing in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

when i executed the below code it is not printing ("yes we can"), its only printing ("all the best"). 
I am running the code in the visual studio.
Executing statement inside if block is not printing in python.

code:

```
team = input("your favorite team")
if team == "Ferrari" :
    print("yes we can")
print("all the best")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwO6r.png)

may anyone please help me.

Comment: and what do you input??? [mcve]

Comment: @JulienBernu: input i am providing is Ferrari

Comment: Unless your input is "Ferrari" *without a trailing newline* "yes we can" will not be printed. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-newline-in-python).

Comment: @JulienBernu: it should print Yes we can after providing Ferrari, but it is only printing all the best.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @SethMMorton - The `input` function removes the linefeed that was used to signal the end of the input stream.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: kindly suggest. how can i correct it please

Comment: There's nothing to correct. That code works fine. If there's something else that may be part of the issue, please include it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: :) very strange..... i tried to post error pic

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/vhWAdnG.png - are you typing Ferrari or copying and pasting it?

Comment: Which are you using, Python 2 or Python 3?  You tagged both,  `input()` is different between them.

Comment: Read [this page on the differences between `input` in Python 2 vs 3](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#parsing-user-inputs-via-input). It doesn't help if you just tag all Python versions to get people to see your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you show indicates a leading space before "Ferrari" which you don't have in your prompt. The strings must be identical.  When I run your code:

```
your favorite teamFerrari
yes we can
all the best
```

But you show a leading space:

```
your favorite team Ferrari
all the best
```

You can fix this in a number of ways.  First choose a better prompt.  Second, strip leading and trailing whitespace:

```
team = input("Your favorite team: ").strip()
```