# writing to file without using quoting marks

Tags: python, telnet

I using the following code to read a txt file with host addresses, line by line, but when the code create and write to file as log, it writing with quoting marks and '?' character:

The code is this:

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

user = "cisco"
password = "cisco"

file = open('hosts.txt', 'r')
for line in file:

        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(line)

        tn.read_until("Username: ")
        tn.write(user + "\n")
        tn.read_until("Password: ")
        tn.write(password + "\n")
        tn.write("enable \n")
        tn.write(password + "\n")

        tn.write("sh ver | i revision \n")
        tn.write("exit \n")

        str_all = tn.read_all()
        log = open(line + ".txt","w")
        log.write(str_all)
        tn.close()
```

So the file created is this:

```
[temp@ser1 Projeto]$ ls
21.10.176.4?.txt  clean_up_819  hosts.txt  master.py  test1.txt  teste.txt
```

Then when I use *cat* the file is displaing with question marks:

```
[noctemp@svcactides Projeto_QoS]$ cat '21.10.176.4
.txt'
```

Is there any way to save in a file normalized called only **21.10.176.4.txt** ?

Answer (score 0):

Your file name does not have quotes; those were added by your shell's tab-completion to protect the newline that it *does* have.

The newline came from `line`, which has it so that you can detect whether the last line has one (and for convenience when re-writing a similar file).  See [How can I remove (chomp) a newline in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-newline-in-python?s=1|9.6488).