# File manipulation: lists, removing `\n`s

Tags: python

Code:

```
with open ("Test1_Votes.txt", 'r'):
    f = open("Test1_Votes.txt")
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(lines[0])
    print(lines[1])
    all_lines = []

    lines = lines.rstrip("\n") #does not work
    for line in lines:
        #in here
        all_lines.append(line)
    print(all_lines)
```

Right now it prints outputs something like:
    ['1,2,3,0,0\n', ...]
    I would like it to output [[1, 2, 3, 0, 0], ...]

File Sample:

1,2,3,0,0

1,3,2,0,0

2,3,1,0,0

3,0,1,2,0

3,0,1,0,2

The zero's must be kept in there and there is not a blank line in between each line in the .txt

Any suggestions/answers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a sample of the file's contents?

Comment: What is content of Test1_Votes.txt?

Comment: Done! I have updated the question with it.

Comment: You do not need to open the file again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove (chomp) a newline in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-newline-in-python)

Comment: Please select an answer as correct if it helped you with your question. Editing the title to say "answered" is not the correct way to indicate your problem has been solved. it is detrimental to those searching for similar questions finding yours in the future so they don't have to ask a duplicate question.

Comment: @Aaron How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently stripping the new line character only from the last line of the file, if any. You should strip from each line instead:

```
with open ("Test1_Votes.txt") as f:
    all_lines = []
    for line in f: 
        line = line.rstrip("\n")                  # strip new line character
        lst = [int(x) for x in line.split(',')]   # split line and cast to int
        all_lines.append(lst)
```

Of course, you can put the entire logic into a list comprehension:

```
with open ("Test1_Votes.txt") as f:
    all_lines = [[int(x) for x in l.rstrip("\n").split(',')] for l in f]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it seems to work well but is there a way to change each value from a string to an integer?

Comment: Thank you very much, I probably saw your question before you edited it.

Comment: I typically recommend against nested list comprehensions and one liners in general unless you're on [pcg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). they can make bugs hard to find as so much is going on in a single line.

Answer (score 5):

You have a few minor glitches in your code.  The `with` context opens the file, so you don't need the second `open` statement.  `lines` is a list of each line in your file, including the trailing `'\n'` characters, to remove them you can iterate over the `lines` list and strip off the new line characters.

```
with open("Test1_Votes.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()]
    print(lines[0])
    print(lines[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
fle=open("infile.txt", "r")
lst=fle.readlines()
lst=[i.strip() for i in lst]
for i in lst:

    print i
print lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.split()` instead of `readlines()`:

```
import re

your_file='abc def\nghi jkl\nmno pqr...'
all_lines=re.split('\n', your_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner might look like this:

```
all_lines = list([int(x) for x in line.replace('\n', '').split(',')] for line in open ("filepath", 'r').readlines())
print(all_lines)
```