# Concatenating two strings

Tags: python, selenium, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two strings, the problem i'm running into is that when I concatenate, the text goes to the next line. I am using `selenium import webdriver`. My code is:

```
randomNum = ""
tries = 0

while (tries < 5):
    randomNum += str(random.randint(0, 9))
    tries = tries + 1

input = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
email = name + randomNum
input.send_keys(email)
print email
```

I have also tried

```
randomNum = []
tries = 0

while (tries < 5):
    randomNum.append(random.randint(0, 9))
    tries = tries + 1

input = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
email = name + "".join(str(num) for num in randomNum)
input.send_keys(email)
print email
```

But when I `print email` my output is something like

`Indoana
16029`

I don't know why this is, I need it to be `Indoana16029`

Comment: next line, when it enters the email into the site it just enters the name and then seems like it presses enter because the email setup moves on to the next thing.

Comment: RandomNum.ToString() maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `name` variable might be contaminated with a new line

have you tried something like this:
[How can I remove (chomp) a newline in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-newline-in-python)

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I just changed `email = name + randomNum` to `email = name.rstrip() + randomNum.rstrip()`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to strip `randomNum`.