# Replacing special characters in a list in Python

Tags: python, replace, special-characters, list-comprehension

I am trying to get rid of special characters inside a list :

```
file_stuff
['John Smith\n', '\n', 'Gardener\n', '\n', 'Age 27\n', '\n', 'Englishman']

file_stuff_new = [x for x in file_stuff if x != '\n']
file_stuff_new = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in file_stuff_new]
file_stuff_new

['John Smith', 'Gardener', 'Age 27', 'Englishman']
```

This apparently works.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Note that a list comprehension will *generate* a list, not modify one.  Are you storing the result of the list comprehension somewhere and looking at that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove (chomp) a trailing newline in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-trailing-newline-in-python)

Comment: Please update your question with the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use strip(), as:

```
file_stuff = map(lambda s: s.strip(), file_stuff)
print(file_stuff)
// ['John Smith', '', 'Gardener', '', 'Age 27', '', 'Englishman']
```

use filter if you want to remove empty items from list, like

```
file_stuff = filter(None, map(lambda s: s.strip(), file_stuff))
```

Comment: You could add `filter(None,file_stuff)` to remove the empty strings

Comment: Note: In python3 you need to enclose map object with `list()`.

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti just a bit of polish. nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a raw string literal.

`r'\n'` is not the newline character, it's a string of length two containing the characters "\" and "n".

```
>>> r'\n'
'\\n'
>>> len(r'\n')
2
```

Otherwise, your original approach works (almost) fine.

```
>>> file_stuff = ['John Smith\n', '\n', 'Gardener\n', '\n', 'Age 27\n', '\n', 'Englishman']
>>> [x.replace('\n', '') for x in file_stuff]
['John Smith', '', 'Gardener', '', 'Age 27', '', 'Englishman']
```

We can filter out the empty strings like this:

```
>>> file_stuff = ['John Smith\n', '\n', 'Gardener\n', '\n', 'Age 27\n', '\n', 'Englishman']
>>> no_newline = (x.replace('\n', '') for x in file_stuff)
>>> result = [x for x in no_newline if x]
>>> result
['John Smith', 'Gardener', 'Age 27', 'Englishman']
```

where `no_newline` is a memory efficient generator that does not build an intermediary temporary list.

If you just want to strip whitespace and newline-characters from the beginning and end of your strings, consider the `str.strip` method.

```
>>> file_stuff = ['John Smith\n', '\n', 'Gardener\n', '\n', 'Age 27\n', '\n', 'Englishman']
>>> no_newline = (x.strip() for x in file_stuff)
>>> result = [x for x in no_newline if x]
>>> result
['John Smith', 'Gardener', 'Age 27', 'Englishman']
```

This could be shortened to

```
>>> result = [x.strip() for x in file_stuff if x.strip()]
>>> result
['John Smith', 'Gardener', 'Age 27', 'Englishman']
```

if you can deal with the inelegancy of calling `str.strip` twice per string.

Comment: I guess that instead of calling `strip()` twice you could use a regular expression to remove what you need to be removed. Not sure about the performance though.

Comment: @ChatterOne you could also use `result = [y for x in file_stuff for y in [x.strip()] if y]` but that just makes things worse. I included the last one more for educational reasons, to illustrate why I think that creating the generator is a good approach. I think it's certainly more readable than map/filter chains. Regex might be a bit overkill for this task, but will certainly work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try mapping your list to a function like replace:

```
file_stuff = map(lambda x: x.replace("\n", ""), file_stuff)
```

Comment: I think you should reverse the order of the arguments

Answer (score 0):

This example is simple list-comprehension with condition :

```
>>> stuff = ['John Smith\n', '\n', 'Gardener\n', '\n', 'Age 27\n', '\n', 'Englishman']
>>> pure = [i.strip() for i in stuff if i.strip()]
>>> print(pure)
['John Smith', 'Gardener', 'Age 27', 'Englishman']
```