# Want to avoid the blank new line in the last of the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't want the empty line to be printed in the output

I have tried `end=""` but since `print` is in `loop`, it is not working

```py
def main():
    a=int(input())
    b=int(input())
    for i in range(a,b+1):
        prime=0
        for x in range(2,i):
            if(i%x==0):
                prime=prime+1
            else:
                prime=prime+0
        if(prime==0):
            print(i, end="") 
main()
```

Actual result:

```
907
911
919
929
937
941
947
953
967
971
977
983
991
997
```

Expected:

```
907
911
919
929
937
941
947
953
967
971
977
983
991
997
```

Comment: It is hard to distinguish your expected result from your actual result. Also, your code prints no newlines at all, so neither your expected nor your actual output match the code.

Comment: With that code, all the numbers should be written on one line without any spaces. Are you adding newlines somehow? If the numbers are all on their own line then naturally the last one will end with one as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to assemble the results into a list and print that list (joined by `'\n'`) at the end:

```
def main():
    a=int(input())
    b=int(input())
    results = []
    for i in range(a,b+1):
        prime=0
        for x in range(2,i):
            if(i%x==0):
                prime=prime+1
            else:
                prime=prime+0
        if(prime==0):
            results.append(i)
    print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in results))
main()
```

I am not completely sure what you are trying to do, you could also experiment with replacing the `print` statement in the above code by

```
print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in results), end = '')
```

Comment: print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in results), end = '')

Thanks, This statement worked out. Can u explain it a bit? How it didnt printed another line at the last

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this: [how can I remove a trailing newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-a-trailing-newline). It states to use .rstrip() but you should read the docs to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically print things out like this

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, sep=' ', end='', flush=True)
```

This will output:

> 123456789

see [Print in one line dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically) for more algorithms that might fit what you need!