# How to skip "\n" when using string join function in Python?

Tags: python, string

For example, I have the code here:

```
string_list = ['a', 'b', 'c\n', 'd', 'e', 'f']
print(' '.join(string_list))
```

The output will be:

```
a b c
 d e f
```

How to get the result of:

```
a b c
d e f
```

instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a trailing newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-a-trailing-newline)

Comment: What's the context for this? It seems rather awkward, no?

Comment: Sorry for lacking the background... I am just learning Python and playing with Jupyter Notebook...

Comment: That's fine, don't worry, I was just curious. It's a toy example?

Comment: Yes, I am trying the join() function, and trying to add '\n' just for fun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
string_list = ['a', 'b', 'c\n', 'd', 'e', 'f']

output = "".join(x + " " if not "\n" in x else x for x in string_list)[:-1]

print(output)
```

Output:

```
a b c
d e f
```

---

As @wjandrea pointed out, we can use `s if s.endswith('\n') else s + ' ' for s in string_list` instead of `x + " " if not "\n" in x else x for x in string_list`. We could also use `x if x[-1] == "\n" else x + " " for x in string_list`. Both are a bit cleaner.

Comment: Because else it leaves a  trailing `" "` :)

Comment: I can up with a pretty similar generator but I think it's slightly clearer: `s if s.endswith('\n') else s + ' ' for s in string_list`

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple if you ignore `join` entirely.

```
string_list = ['a', 'b', 'c\n', 'd', 'e', 'f']
output = ""
for string in string_list:
    output += string + (" " if not string.endswith("\n") else "")
output = output.rstrip() # If you don't want a trailing " ".
```

Comment: This would remove the `"\n"` as well, which the OP has showed in their desired output...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when rstrip() applied, the text "d e f" will not go into a new line.

Comment: I think this code worked before the `.rstrip()` was added.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answering my question. I came up with a solution myself:

```
string_list = ['a', 'b', 'c\n', 'd', 'e', 'f']
joined_string = ' '.join(string_list)
print(joined_string.replace('\n ', '\n'))
```

It works!