# Whitespaces remove from a matrix in file in python

Tags: python

```
def main():
    f=open("fileread.txt","r")
    for x in f:
        p=x.split(" ")
        print(p)
main()
```

I have written this code for reading a matrix from a file and write it into the console. But I got unexpected output.
The output should be

```
    ['5', '6', '9', '7']
    ['1', '7', '9', '6']
    ['4', '5', '6', '3']
    ['14', '25', '9', '6']
```

but I got

```
    ['5', '6', '9', '7\n']
    ['1', '7', '9', '6', '\n']
    ['4', '5', '6', '3', '\n']
    ['14', '25', '9', '6']
```

My Text file is written just like that  :

```
5 6 9 7
1 7 9 6 
4 5 6 3 
14 25 9 6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a trailing newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-a-trailing-newline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` represents a new line.

You can strip them like this:

```
def main():
    f=open("fileread.txt","r")
    for x in f:
        p=x.rstrip("\n").split(" ")
        print(p)
main()
```

I'd suggest using a csv file and [Python's csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) which will handle things like this for you.

@Muts actually made a better suggestion in comment !

Comment: You could just use `x.split()` empty strings won't be returned when separator isn't defined

Answer (score 2):

Just use `x.split()` instead of `x.split(" ")`. `x.split()` will remove multiple spaces, newlines, tabs and all other forms of whitespace.

```python
def main():
    f=open("fileread.txt","r")
    for x in f:
        p=x.split()
        print(p)

main()
```

Input:

```
5 6 9 7
1 7 9 6
4 5 6 3
14 25 9 6
```

Output:

```
['5', '6', '9', '7']
['1', '7', '9', '6']
['4', '5', '6', '3']
['14', '25', '9', '6']
```