# Removing New line character at end of last line only python

Tags: python

i have seen many other questions but it all shows how to remove all \n characters.

```
def copy_lines(input, output, c):

    with open("essay.txt","r") as f:
        with open("out.txt","w") as s:
            counter=0
            
            for i in f:
                counter+=1
                if c==1:                    
                    data=i.strip()
                    s.write(data)
                else:
                    data=i
                    s.write(data)
                                             
                if counter==c:
                    break
```

i get output of this
`'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem\n\nThe title is the first thing potential answerers will see.\n\n'`
and i want it like this
`'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem\n\nThe title is the first thing potential answerers will see.`
so what i should modify?
i am picking up no of lines called c from a text file and writing it in another text file
so i dont want the last line to add \n when i check it with ''' '''

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a trailing newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-a-trailing-newline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to remove "\n" from the end then you can simply use

```
with open("essay.txt",'r') as f:
    a_string=f.read()

c=3
a_string='\n'.join(a_string.splitlines()[:c]) #EDIT
a_string = a_string.rstrip("\n")  # rstrip helps to strip only from right

with open("out.txt",'w') as f:
    f.write(a_string)
```

OR

```
a_string='Write a title that summarizes the specific problem\n\nThe title is the first thing potential answerers will see.\n\n'
c=3
a_string='\n'.join(a_string.splitlines()[:c])
a_string=a_string.rstrip("\n")
print(a_string)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> Write a title that summarizes the specific problem\n\nThe title is the first thing potential answerers will see.
```

Comment: its working for a specific lines but if i add this code in my loop it removes all \n

Comment: @ShaheryarAshfaq why are you adding the code in a loop?

Comment: from the text file i have to pick 3 lines only so i am using loop so that i can pick 1st 3 lines
no of lines to be picked will be given in question so i have to make a general code that doesnt end with \n

Comment: @ShaheryarAshfaq Is this what you wanted?