# Time comparison using strptime in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, strptime

I want to execute further when the difference between `now()` and datetime in service.txt file is greater than 25 seconds for that I tried the below code, but got error.

service.txt:

```
2021-07-19 21:39:07.876953
```

Python code:

```
then = open("service.txt","r").read()
duration = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.strptime(then, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
if str(duration) > '0:00:25.0' :
    # do something
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\python_projects\test.py", line 41, in <module>
    duration = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.strptime(then, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
   File "C:\Python\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
   File "C:\Python\lib\_strptime.py", line 365, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():]) ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of `then` is `2021-07-19 21:39:07.876953\n`.
Note the newline character at the end which you are not accounting for while using `strptime`.

You can fix it either by

1. replacing `\n` with `''` in `then`

```
then = open("service.txt","r").read().replace('\n', '')
```

2. including `\n` in the date format string:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(then, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

The file presumably contains a newline character `\n` at the end, which is included in the return value of `read()`.

You have to remove it from the timestamp before passing it to `strptime`, for example by using the `rstrip` method (see [How can I remove a trailing newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-a-trailing-newline)):

```
then = open("service.txt","r").read().rstrip()
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't knew `rstrip` removed newline character. Even the docstring - "....trailing whitespace removed" doesn't explicitly state that.

Comment: Newlines are whitespace.