# Difference detween line.rstrip("\n") and line.rstrip(os.linesep)?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

Real quick question, what is the difference between `line.strip("\n")` and `line.rstrip(os.linesep)`? Especially, when using them in the Fasta file and other bioinformatics fields.

Comment: Specifically, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5803510/)

Answer (score 1):

`line.strip("\n")` removes the new-line character for UNIX and UNIX-like OSs. On the other side, `line.strip(os.linesep)` would automatically change to the correct new-line character for your current operation system (Mac OS, Linux, Windows, etc)

Comment: But the newline sequence for Windows is `\r\n`, not `\n`. `\n` is the newline sequence for Unix and Unix-like systems, and `\r` is the newline sequence for the traditional MacOS (note the capitalization) but not the Unix-based macOS.

Comment: Apologies, I confused that part. I will correct that now.

Comment: Dank! But why the python doc says never use the os.sepline in any cases? [https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.linesep]

Comment: Check the question linked as duplicate (What is os.linesep for), as it will contain the answer to that question

Comment: Because you don't know what system that file is going to be used in, so if you use the specific character for windows the file will not be correct when used on Linux, for example.

Comment: I think Andrew meant why the os.sepline should *not* be used. Which is a bit of a confusion about the "text mode". @Shinratensei