# Python file.write() is adding an extra newline after a variable in a concatenated string

Tags: python, concatenation, newline

I have been trying to solve this issue. I have written:

```py
file.write("pyautogui.write(" + "'" + textEntry + "'" + ")")
```

but in the file that is written to, the following is written:

```py
pyautogui.write('test
')
```

I want it all to be on one line. Does anyone know the cause for this? I have tried fixing it, but to no avail.

Comment: Try `textEntry.strip()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here is that the textEntry variable likely has a \n character at the end of it, a simple way to solve that is by using strip().  Also, it is generally recommended to use f-Strings instead of doing the + each time.  A solution is as follows:

```
file.write(f"pyautogui.write('{textEntry.strip()}')")
```

Comment: I didn't even think about there being a newline at the end of the textEntry variable. Also, in layman's terms, does .strip() just remove any extra whitespace or escape characters from a string?

Comment: @CnutCnutson The `.strip()` method removes all whitespace characters that are at the start and end of the string, so `"  hello\n "` becomes `"hello"`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your `textEntry` variable probably has a newline character at the end.

you should try stripping newlines and spaces from the end of the string if that is all you want to do so something like:

```py
file.write("pyautogui.write(" + "'" + textEntry.rstrip() + "'" + ")")
```

here is some more info on rstrip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/275025/13282454

Answer (score 0):

I think your `textEntry` is like that

```
    textEntry = '''
text
'''
```

so it has a newline. try to remove it and write simply

```
`textEntry='text'`
```

Answer (score 0):

As there will always be a trailing newline character *(`\n`)* in the `textEntry` string, all you'll have to do is use a slice that leaves out the last character in the string:

```
file.write("pyautogui.write(" + "'" + textEntry[:-1] + "'" + ")")
```

You can also make use of Python formatted strings:

```
file.write(f"pyautogui.write('{textEntry[:-1]}')")
```