# strip all strings in list of specific character

Tags: python

I have been looking for an answer to this for a while but keep finding answers about stripping a specific string from a list.

Let's say this is my list of strings

`stringList = ["cat\n","dog\n","bird\n","rat\n","snake\n"]`

But all list items contain a new line character (\n)

How can I remove this from all the strings within the list?

Comment: Iterate over the list, call `.strip()` on each word, and assign the result back to the list.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a trailing newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-do-i-remove-a-trailing-newline)

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension with `rstrip()`:

```py
stringList = ["cat\n","dog\n","bird\n","rat\n","snake\n"]
output = [x.rstrip() for x in stringList]
print(output)  # ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'rat', 'snake']
```

If you really want to target a single newline character only at the end of each string, then we can get more precise with `re.sub`:

```py
stringList = ["cat\n","dog\n","bird\n","rat\n","snake\n"]
output = [re.sub(r'\n$', '', x) for x in stringList]
print(output)  # ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'rat', 'snake']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) along with [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
>>> string_list = ['cat\n', 'dog\n', 'bird\n', 'rat\n', 'snake\n']
>>> new_string_list = list(map(str.rstrip, string_list))
>>> new_string_list
['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'rat', 'snake']
```

Answer (score 1):

By applying the method `strip` (or `rstrip`) to all terms of the list with `map`

```
out = list(map(str.strip, stringList))
print(out)
```

or with a more rudimental check and slice

```
strip_char = '\n'
out = [s[:-len(strip_char)] if s.endswith(strip_char) else s for s in stringList]
print(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can use an if to check if a new line character exists in a string, you can use the code below to detect string elements with the new line character and replace those characters with empty strings

```
stringList = ["cat\n","dog\n","bird\n","rat\n","snake\n"]
nlist = []
for string in stringList:
    if "\n" in string:
        nlist.append(string.replace("\n" , ""))
print(nlist)
```