# string in file on one line

Tags: python, string, file

I have a file like this

```
A0001
/1536.
/1537.
/1511.
/1451.
/1388.
/1323.
/1322.


# And so on...
```

I used json .format to make it like this

```
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="resources/images/thumb/A0001
.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="resources/images/thumb/1536
.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="resources/images/thumb/1537
.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="resources/images/thumb/1511
.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="resources/images/thumb/1451
.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="resources/images/thumb/1388
.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="resources/images/thumb/1323
.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="resources/images/thumb/1322
.png"width="64" height="64"></div>


#And so on
```

But that's not the output I was looking for, what I'm looking for is this:

```
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title=""src="resources/images/thumb/1242.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title=""src="resources/images/thumb/1536.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title=""src="resources/images/thumb/1242.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
```

I want every string to be on one line. as I'm new to python and I don't know what to search for to get an answer to my question, **This is my code**

```
import re
import pyperclip
import json

def remove_punc(string):
    punc = '''!()-[]{};:'"\, <>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    for ele in string:  
        if ele in punc:  
            string = string.replace(ele, "") 
    return string




d = '<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="resources/images/thumb/{}.png"></div>'

rex = re.compile(p)


f= open('txte.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines() 



results = [remove_punc(i) for i in lines]

f.close()

fp= open("data1.txt", "w")
for item in results:
    print(d.format(item), file=fp)

fp.close()
```

Comment: Maybe `results = [remove_punc(i.strip()) for i in lines]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the newline character (`'\n'`) from the end of each line. This can be done with `strip`.

I rewrote the `remove_punc` function to use [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to make it faster.

This replaces your full code example.

```
def remove_punc(text, punc='''!()-[]{};:'"\, <>./?@#$%^&*_~'''):
    return text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', punc)).strip()

with open('txte.txt') as names, open("data1.txt", "w") as target:
    for name in names:
        target.write(f'<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="resources/images/thumb/{remove_punc(name)}.png"></div>\n')
```

Comment: you went beyond what I thought of!
Thanks this is a fantastic answer!

Comment: Some short explanations: I used the `with` statement to automatically close the files. I dropped `readlines` because you can iterate over the lines of a text file. I used an f-string instead of format. I added a second parameter with a default value to `remove_punc` so that you can provide the function with a different set of characters. And `translate` ... well, I knew that it existed and had to look it up in the documentation. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing an action to strip the new line.

You could add a replace after the first replace like this

```
def remove_punc(string):
    punc = '''!()-[]{};:'"\, <>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    for ele in string:  
        if ele in punc:  
            string = string.replace(ele, "")**.replace('\n','')**
    return string
```

Maybe take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-do-i-remove-a-trailing-newline).

Comment: Your answer worked for all the lines except the first line.
@user56700 comment has worked perfectly.