# Why does blitted text on screen have a rectangle behind it in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a small game about chickens and I ran into something I could not find a solution for. The problem is that my text has a small rectangle behind it, as shown here: [The number of coins and a rectangle behind it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWudi.jpg)
I have also figured out that the error is coming from reading a text file, the code is:

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pg = pygame

coins = 0
eggs = 0
time_left = 12
chickens = 0
grain = 0

with open('stats.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = f.readlines()
    coins = a[0]
    eggs = a[1]
    time_left = a[2]
    chickens = a[3]
    grain = a[4]

font = pg.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 28)
text = font.render(coins,False,(255,255,255))

run = True
while run:
    surface.fill(0)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False
    surface.blit(text,(20,-2))
    pg.display.update()
```

The text file is:

```
0
0
12.0
0
0
```

I do not think I can change the way I am getting information from the file, but if you know a way of doing it and it works, you can let me know.

Comment: What is the value of `coins` when the line `text = font.render(coins,False,(255,255,255))` is reached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the text there is a character that cannot be displayed. The last character of the text is `\n`, because each line in the text file ends with a *newline*. So just remove the tailing newline from the text (see [How do I remove a trailing newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-do-i-remove-a-trailing-newline)):

<s>`coins = a[0]`</s>

```py
coins = a[0].rstrip()
```